# How to upgrade all Python packages with pip

Tags: python, pip

Is it possible to upgrade all Python packages at one time with **[`pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip)**?

**Note**: that there is [a feature request](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4551) for this on the official issue tracker.

Comment: Beware [software rot](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/02/27/managing-node-js-dependencies-with-shrinkwrap/)—upgrading dependencies might break your app. You can list the exact version of all installed packages with `pip freeze` (like `bundle install` or `npm shrinkwrap`). Best to save a copy of that before tinkering.

Comment: If you want to update a single package and all of *its* dependencies (arguably a more sensible approach), do this: pip install -U --upgrade-strategy eager your-package

Comment: I use PowerShell 7 and currently I use this one-liner: `pip list --format freeze | %{pip install --upgrade $_.split('==')[0]}` (I am unable to post an answer here yet)

Comment: For those wondering like me, the was until recently pip didn't have a dependency resolver. https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4551

Answer (score 2871, accepted):

There isn't a built-in flag yet. Starting with pip version 22.3, the `--outdated` and `--format=freeze` have become [mutually exclusive](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#v22-3). Use Python, to parse the JSON output:

```bash
pip --disable-pip-version-check list --outdated --format=json | python -c "import json, sys; print('\n'.join([x['name'] for x in json.load(sys.stdin)]))" | xargs -n1 pip install -U
```

If you are using `pip<22.3` you can use:

```bash
pip list --outdated --format=freeze | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 pip install -U
```

For older versions of `pip`:

```bash
pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 pip install -U
```

---

- The `grep` is to skip editable ("-e") package definitions, as suggested by @jawache. (Yes, you could replace `grep`+`cut` with `sed` or `awk` or `perl` or...).
- The `-n1` flag for `xargs` prevents stopping everything if updating one package fails (thanks [@andsens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/339505/andsens)).

---

**Note:** there are infinite potential variations for this. I'm trying to keep this answer short and simple, but please do suggest variations in the comments!

Comment: Right :( The issue now lives at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/59 . But every suggestion seems to be answered with "Yeah, but I'm too sure if X is the right way to do Y"... Now is better than never? Practicality beats purity? :(

Comment: It also prints those packages that were installed with a normal package manager (like apt-get or Synaptic). If I execute this `pip install -U`, it will update all packages. I'm afraid it can cause some conflict with apt-get.

Comment: Spot on - added an exclude to the grep to ignore editable packages. pip freeze --local | grep -v "\-e" | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs pip install -U

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost I've been trying to keep it simple. But, well, make sense. I've included it (with a small fix: I've pinned the regex to the beginning of the package name, in order to avoid excluding packages like "<something>-e<something else>".

Comment: How about changing grep to: egrep -v '^(\-e|#)' (i get this line when running it on ubuntu 12.10: "## FIXME: could not find svn URL in dependency_links for this package:".

Comment: You could also just use *sed*, for a much simpler line, e.g. (and this doesn't hit everything you included, but in principle it easily could): `pip freeze --local | sed 's/==.*//' | xargs pip install -U`.

Comment: How about this **pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -i bash -c 'pip install -U {} || :'** to prevent exit on error?

Comment: I'd throw in a `tee` before doing the actual upgrade so that you can get a list of the original verisons. E.g.  `pip freeze --local | tee before_upgrade.txt | ...` That way it would be easier to revert if there's any problems.

Comment: @EmilH there are endless possibilities of enhancing or customising this :) I won't add your suggestion to the answer, to keep it simple (as much as possible). But it's a good one, thanks :)

Comment: If for some reason pip fails in the middle of it all (i.e. a package no longer exists) you can add `-n1` to `xargs`, this makes it pass only one argument at a time to pip, otherwise pip quits on the first error.

Comment: @andsens Is there any reason to not use -n1? Seems like it might make sense to include it by default...

Comment: @CrawfordComeaux No, not that I can think of :-)

Comment: The following incantation is updated to use pip list --outdated. It ignores any error or warning messages and does not consider them. `pip list --outdated | grep -G '(Current.*)' | sed 's/ (Current.*//' | xargs -n 1 sudo pip install --upgrade`

Comment: @richard-bronosky I've reverted your edit, although it was perfectly valid and probably even a good idea. As I've mentioned before, there are infinite variations of this solution, and I'm trying to keep the solution simple and as short as it's reasonable.

For the record, Richard's solution was:

pip freeze --local | tee before.pip.txt | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 pip install -U

(i.e., including "tee" to create a "before.pip.txt" file with the contents of "pip freeze" before the upgrade)

Comment: @rbp, that's fair. I have some suggestions since code golfing is the goal. (You said "simple and as short as it's reasonable") Instead of piping grep & cut, you can save **a process** and chars by using a single tool. Save 3 chars with awk `pip freeze --local |  awk -F = '!/^-e/{print $1}' | xargs -n1 pip install -U` or 10 chars with sed `pip freeze --local |  sed '/^-e/d;s/=.*//' | xargs -n1 pip install -U`.

Comment: User installed packages (i.e. those in ~/.local) should be handled separately, or they would be replaced with non-user installs. This looks like a decent task for a Github gist until pip has upgrade-all.

Comment: Adding a sudo to the last element was required for me: pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | sudo xargs -n1 pip install -

Comment: @LukeDupin if you're installing packages globally, then yes, you might need that. If you're using virtualenv, it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Good example of pipes, but I would still use pip-review. Simple is better than complex;)

Comment: @FredrikHedman Perhaps, I've never used pip-review. You'll notice that this answer is *way* older than pip-review :)

Comment: I added `-H` to `sudo` to avoid an annoying error message:  `$ pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 sudo -H pip install -U`

Comment: pip list --outdated | grep -v 'sqlite3 (0.0.0)' | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | xargs -n1 pip install -U

(to avoid upgrading sqilte3)

Comment: Getting errors when running the above command on OSX, this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25816730/2737316 solved the issue. i.e. run: ``pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 pip install -U --user``

Comment: I highly recommend running `pip check` afterwards to check if any upgrades caused a dependency to no longer be satisfied for another package.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use xargs `-P` to parallelize the updates?

Comment: The output is hard to read for outdated answer. This one is excellent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/upgrading-all-packages-with-pip/42334797#42334797

Comment: `Permission denied`... Any way to prevent this operating on system packages?

Comment: In order to get rid of the permission issue, you might want to change it a bit into $pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 sudo -H pip install -U

Comment: @rbp [Issue #59](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/59) is closed and references to [upgrade-all command #4551](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4551), which depends on a not yet implemented [dependency resolver #988](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/988)

Comment: This is exhaustive, it runs `--upgrade` on all packages , waste of time, we would upgrade the ones which are outdated right.

Comment: @pradyunsg, add `xargs -r` to prevent running upgrade commands if nothing to upgrade! :)

Comment: To upgrade for logged in user (so doesn't require sudo):  
pip3 freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 pip install --user -U

Comment: Another reason to use `pip list --outdated --format=freeze` instead of `pip freeze --local` is that the latter does not upgrade `pip` itself if needed.

Comment: This failed on Windows 7: `'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Why the ˋxargsˋ?

Comment: `pip 10` has added `--exclude-editable` option. https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#id30

Comment: The output can be ambiguous when using this command. For a much more easily readable output, use this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/upgrading-all-packages-with-pip/42334797#42334797

Comment: In Python 3 there will be an error `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'Version' and 'Version'`

Comment: @QinHeyang I don't follow. The command-line on the answer runs on bash. If you're getting this error, it's something to do with pip.

Comment: Has anyone figured out how to do this on Windows?

Comment: There seems to be a bug in the current version of pip that I have reported here: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8331. When I run this command, pkg_resources==0.0.0 is getting added. Omitted -U in pip install seems to work

Comment: pip was listing itself as outdated, which was breaking my brew installation. removing pip from the list of packages to update helps: `pip list --outdated --format=freeze | grep -v "pip=="| grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | grep -v pip | xargs -n1 pip install -U`. Of course if another package ends with "pip" then it won't get updated, either :)

Comment: As of August 2020, this gives me many messages like so `ERROR: After October 2020 you may experience errors when installing or updating packages. This is because pip will change the way that it resolves dependency conflicts.`

is there a way to upgrade to dependencies along with the actual module?

Comment: `pip list` has a `--not-required` option, which excludes packages that are dependencies of other installed packages.

Comment: @Omglolyes Got the same error. Added `--use-feature=2020-resolver` at the end of the command and that resolved it.

Comment: Seems like on Ubuntu, this also "updates" to an old version of `distro-info`, which breaks `do-release-upgrade`. See this AskUbuntu question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182208/problem-with-upgrading-19-04-to-19-10-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-d

Comment: Why show the cmd for older pip versions, is this still in use? Should I use an old pip version?

Comment: Python3 version:
`pip3 list --outdated --format=freeze | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 pip3 install -U`

Comment: What is grep -v '^\-e' doing? Ah, read the whole post first!

Comment: I recently discovered that `pip list` has a `--user` option, which restricts the output to the user's *site-packages*. This avoids messing with *distro-info* on Ubuntu, which can cause serious [problems](https://github.com/pypa/pypi-support/issues/589).

Comment: This has stopped working and gives a TypeError now.

Comment: careful using this because it will likely override your distribution python packages

Comment: `pip list --outdated --format=freeze | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1 | xargs -n1 pip install -U --user` - This is also a useful command.

Comment: What about adding `-r` to xargs, so it won't run `pip -U` _at all_ if there are no outdated packages? I did find this useful, otherwise I'd get the annoying message  `ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")`  if I'd type that command in some environment with no outdated packages. NOTE: it seems `-r` option to xargs is a GNU extension. Enjoy!

Comment: The grep-to-cut seems silly (and only gets sillier in the comments that grep multiple times), the output of `--format freeze` screams `awk`. `pip list -o --format freeze | awk 'BEGIN { FS="==" } { print $1 }' | xargs -n1 pip install -U`

Comment: Nit: a superfluous space in the current edition of the answer, this part of the command (before the pipe): `cut -d = -f 1  |`

Comment: With latest pip format 'freeze' can not be used with the --outdated option anymore.

Comment: For those (like me) who did not understand instantly: pip3 --disable-pip-version-check list --outdated --format=json | python3 -c "import json, sys; print('\n'.join([x['name'] for x in json.load(sys.stdin)]))" | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 pip3 install -U

Comment: You can use `pip3 list --outdated --format=json | jq -r '.[] | "\(.name)==\(.latest_version)"' | xargs -n1 pip3 install --upgrade`.

Comment: The first command is a lil bit misleading. It just lists the packages, NOT install/upgrade those.

Comment: Plus one for the comment of @Suuuehgi, the cmd works, but one need to install `jq`. The first command lists outdated pip packages, the third cmd works for me: `pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 pip install -U`.

Comment: So the above generates a nice list of packages which have an update available. What is the remaining syntax to actually upgrade the identified packages; for WINDOWS?

Comment: The answer to my own question is:

`pip --disable-pip-version-check list --outdated --format=json | python -c "import json, sys, subprocess; [subprocess.call(['pip', 'install', '--upgrade', x['name']]) for x in json.load(sys.stdin)]"`

Comment: For pip3 on the mac: `pip3 list --outdated | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n1 pip3 install --upgrade` worked for me.

Answer (score 899):

To upgrade all local packages, you can install [`pip-review`](https://github.com/jgonggrijp/pip-review):

```
$ pip install pip-review
```

After that, you can either upgrade the packages interactively:

```
$ pip-review --local --interactive
```

Or automatically:

```
$ pip-review --local --auto
```

---

`pip-review` is a fork of `pip-tools`. See [`pip-tools` issue](https://github.com/nvie/pip-tools/issues/185) mentioned by [@knedlsepp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/upgrading-all-packages-with-pip/16269635#comment51585726_16269635). `pip-review` package works but `pip-tools` package no longer works. [`pip-review` is looking for a new maintainer.](https://github.com/jgonggrijp/pip-review/issues/76)

`pip-review` works on Windows [since version 0.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/upgrading-all-packages-with-pip/16269635#comment67179492_16269635).

Comment: `NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined` -- Broken for me.

Comment: @hauzer: It doesn't support Python 3. Though [it might be a bug](https://github.com/nvie/pip-tools/pull/43)

Comment: @mkoistinen It's a good tool but until it's merged in PIP it means installing something additional which not everyone may desire to do.

Comment: Works fine with mingw. Why are you using CMD on Windows if you're also using Python?

Comment: @Wernight: if you can't install additional Python packages then you don't need `pip-review` (that automates installing new versions for you). In other words if you are in an environment where it makes sense to use `pip-review` tool then you can afford to install it too.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes pip-review is to upgrade and freeze dependencies. I meant that one will have `pip-review` in its `dev-requirements.txt`. It could become part of PIP.

Comment: @julianz: There is [pip-toos-win](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip-tools-win/0.0.4), although I haven't tried it.

Comment: How to upgrade stuff for Python 3? It does not do so by default.

Comment: @ziyuang create a new virtualenv using Python 3 version and install the necessary packages (`pip-dump` may help you to maintain the requirements file). See [Upgrade python in a virtualenv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218946/upgrade-python-in-a-virtualenv)

Comment: If it no longer works, then shouldn't that be edited into the answer, since so many people don't read comments?

Comment: pip-review works just fine (at least for Python version 3.5.0)

Comment: pip-review should work under Windows as of version 0.5 (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip-review/0.5). Otherwise, please submit a ticket to https://github.com/jgonggrijp/pip-review/issues.

Comment: To skip system packages: `pip-review --auto --user`

Comment: The output can be ambiguous when using this command. For a much more easily readable output, use this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/upgrading-all-packages-with-pip/42334797#42334797

Comment: For Windows, use `python.exe -m pip_review` instead of `pip-review`. (note the underscore instead of the dash)

Comment: pip-review --local --interactive does not seem to work:
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ikq9nwd2/onedrivesdk/setup.py", line 9, in <module>
        with open(NOTICE, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/tmp/pip-install-ikq9nwd2/onedrivesdk/setup.py/../NOTICE.rst'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: @Gerd: it looks like an issue with the `onedrivesdk` package that is unrelated to `pip-review`.

Comment: Doesn't work with proxy, at least I didn't see that option

Comment: It can take a lot of time to complete the run depending on how many packages are installed.

Answer (score 840):

You can use the following Python code. Unlike `pip freeze`, this will not print warnings and FIXME errors.
**For pip < 10.0.1**

```
import pip
from subprocess import call

packages = [dist.project_name for dist in pip.get_installed_distributions()]
call("pip install --upgrade " + ' '.join(packages), shell=True)
```

**For pip >= 10.0.1**

```
import pkg_resources
from subprocess import call

packages = [dist.project_name for dist in pkg_resources.working_set]
call("pip install --upgrade " + ' '.join(packages), shell=True)
```

Comment: This works amazingly well…  It's always so satisfying when a task takes a REALLY _long time_…  and gives you a *bunch* of new stuff!  PS: Run it as root if you're on OS X!

Comment: Is there no way to install using pip without calling a subprocess?  Something like `import pip` `pip.install('packagename')`?

Comment: @aspinei See my answer for Windows version of the shell script.

Comment: I wrapped this up in a [fabfile.py](https://gist.github.com/joshkehn/5485111). Thanks!

Comment: Question, will that upgrade System Packages as well? (Running as root)? If so, is there a way to prevent this instead of using virtualenv? Thanks.

Comment: @BenMezger: You really shouldn't be using system packages in your virtualenv. You also really shouldn't run more than a handful of trusted, well-known programs as root. Run your virtualenvs with --no-site-packages (default in recent versions).

Comment: Thumbs up for this one, the chosen answer (above) fails if a package can't be found any more.  This script simply continues to the next packages, wonderful.

Comment: It's awesome that this can be run within python! If I wanted it to print out whether or not a package was successfully updated, how would I modify this script?

Comment: This doesn't work and possibly screws things up work for dealing with system-wide packages.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. Only one issue came up, if you have two or more Python installations in your Windows, only one gets to upgrade the packages. `pip` in this case is the `pip.exe` of the "default" Python. I changed it to `call("%s\\Scripts\\pip.exe install --upgrade %s" % (dirname(sys.executable), dist.project_name), shell=True)` which of course makes it unusable on non-Windows platforms, though.

Comment: I hope this is the feature that gets implemented in pip package proper. Just a function `pip.updateall()` would be perfect.

Comment: It's weird how `pip` doesn't write `--upgrade` flag in their help

Comment: @AminahNuraini: It does.

Comment: pip freeze has a lot of permission denied for me even with sudo. this answer perfectly solves my problem

Comment: `Permission denied`... Any way to prevent this operating on system packages?

Comment: @TomHale Check the `dist.location` and filter the list accordingly.

Comment: This works with ActiveState ActivePython. However, after you do this, if you try to run a .py file by relying on the file association. Windows will attempt to run the ActiveState ActivePython installer again.

Comment: Also note that this script fails if one package fails to install (which does happen for certain C extensions on Windows), while [the previous version of the script](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5839291/2) will continue upgrading everything else.

Comment: Best answer here. I created a gist on Github here: https://gist.github.com/SeppPenner/efc73891480b67c561aac7ba47df9df7

Comment: The output can be ambiguous when using this command. For a much more easily readable output, use this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/upgrading-all-packages-with-pip/42334797#42334797

Comment: I had to change the last line to `[call("pip install " + name + " --upgrade") for name in packages]`

Comment: @Josh fabric is for ssh, if I do not need ssh is your fabfile also interesting? I ask because the cmd of the answer for pip>10 does not work, I get an error when importing pkg_resources

Comment: @Josh the fabfile does not work in pip >10

Comment: It worked for me on Windows for pip>=10.0.1 without changing anything.

Comment: @0xC0000022L if you change the line `from subprocess import call` to `from subprocess import call, executable` and the call line to `call([executable, "-mpip", "install", "--upgrade"].extend(packages)], shell=True)` then it will call the `pip` for the current executable regardless of platform, venv, etc.

Comment: @SteveBarnes: thanks, agreed, I am aware of that method meanwhile and prefer it even. In addition on Windows I am preaching to people to use the Python loader (`py`) instead of some hardcoded paths to some possibly installed Python. As a side note, between my comment (from 2015) and now, I have also simply tapped into the `pip` module directly instead of doing that via the shell. E.g. in one project I had the project offer the option to pull in missing packages.

Answer (score 473):

The following works on Windows and should be good for others too (`$` is whatever directory you're in, in the command prompt. For example, *C:/Users/Username*).

Do

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Open the text file, replace the `==` with `>=`, or have sed do it for you:

```
$ sed -i 's/==/>=/g' requirements.txt
```

and execute:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade
```

If you have a problem with a certain package stalling the upgrade ([NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) sometimes), just go to the directory ($), comment out the name (add a `#` before it) and run the upgrade again. You can later uncomment that section back. This is also great for copying Python global environments.

---

**Another way:**

I also like the pip-review method:

```
py2
$ pip install pip-review

$ pip-review --local --interactive

py3
$ pip3 install pip-review

$ py -3 -m pip-review --local --interactive
```

You can select 'a' to upgrade all packages; if one upgrade fails, run it again and it continues at the next one.

Comment: You should remove `requirements.txt`'s `=={version}`. For example: `python-dateutil==2.4.2` to `python-dateutil` for all lines.

Comment: I found that this didn't actually upgrade the packages on macOS.

Comment: @youngminz I would recommand a quick 'Replace all "==" > ">=" ' in your editor/ide before running 'pip install...' to fix this

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I have a python virtualenv and I needed keep it up to date. It upgraded all existing packages in the requirements.txt.

Comment: Although I like very much the jfs solution with pip-review, this solution gives you the flexibility to choose what you want upgrade or not, easily.  @Amaury-Liet good catch!

Comment: for linux: `$ pip freeze | cut -d '=' -f1> requirements.txt` in order to remove the version

Comment: If the shell you use is bash, you can shorten it into one command via `pip3 install -r <(pip3 freeze) --upgrade`  Effectively, `<(pip3 freeze)` is an anonymous pipe, but it will act as a file object

Comment: And in case it [fails on a single package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250483/stop-pip-from-failing-on-single-package-when-installing-with-requirements-txt), you can make it `xargs -L 1 -a <(pip3 freeze) pip3 install --upgrade`

Comment: Works for me in Ubuntu 16.04 (with@Cavaz's modification): `$ pip freeze | cut -d '=' -f1> reqs` and then I open file and comment `cytoolz` (using `#`) which was causing errors; finally `$ pip install -r reqs --upgrade`.

Comment: Combine the above comments, this one-liner `pip3 install -r <(pip3 freeze | cut -d '=' -f1) --upgrade` works on Bash.

Comment: As this answer relates to Windows, here is a PS try: `$pfr=$(pip freeze > requirements.txt)
    $pfr=$pfr.split('=')`. Error `WARNING: Could not generate requirement for distribution -p 20.2.3 (c:\python39\lib\site-packages): Parse error at "'-p==20.2'": Expected W:(abcd...)`

Comment: I am on python 3. `py -3 -m pip-review --local --interactive` gave an error: `No module named pip-review`. Simply `pip-review` worked for me.

Comment: In 2023, I had to use: `pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt`

The update gave me errors: OS error file not found. In the generated requirements.txt there were weird paths. Solution comes from: 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62885911/pip-freeze-creates-some-weird-path-instead-of-the-package-version)

Answer (score 293):

#### Use [**pipupgrade**](https://github.com/achillesrasquinha/pipupgrade)! ... last release 2019

```
pip install pipupgrade
pipupgrade --verbose --latest --yes
```

**pipupgrade** helps you upgrade your system, local or packages from a `requirements.txt` file! It also selectively upgrades packages that don't break change.

pipupgrade also ensures to upgrade packages present within multiple Python environments. It is compatible with Python 2.7+, Python 3.4+ and pip 9+, pip 10+, pip 18+, pip 19+.

[image]

Note: I'm the author of the tool.

Comment: Nice idea, but it's stuck at `Checking...` forever when I tried it.

Comment: @CGFoX I believe that's been fixed with 1.5.0

Comment: @Chris @CGFoX Try deleting pip cache `~/.cache/pip` and `~/Library/Caches/pip` (on macOS)

Comment: Added this as a Known Issue - https://github.com/achillesrasquinha/pipupgrade/issues/30

Comment: Got an error on Windows 10 and Python 3.7.5: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ctypes.windll'`

Comment: @QinHeyang this has been fixed recently.

Comment: raspberry Pi Jessie need sudo pip to install

Comment: It seems that this will upgrade all packages to the latest version and that may break some dependencies.

Comment: @user202729 you could then not use the `--latest` flag since it upgrades dependencies that possibly break change.

Comment: Fails on my venv. It seems to try to run /usr/bin/pip2 from the OS which fails.

Comment: Why would you say this tool avoids breaking changes but only provide the way to run it that DOES install breaking changes?

Answer (score 161):

Windows version after consulting the excellent [documentation for `FOR`](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntfor.php#FOR_F) by Rob van der Woude:

```
for /F "delims===" %i in ('pip freeze') do pip install --upgrade %i
```

Comment: `for /F "delims= " %i in ('pip list --outdated') do pip install -U %i
`  
  

Quicker since it'll only try and update "outdated" packages

Comment: @RefaelAckermann I suspect this will be slower than the original :) To know which packages are outdated pip has to first check what's the latest version of each package. It does exactly the same as the first step when updating and does not proceed if there's no newer version available. However in your version pip will check versions two times, the first time to establish the list of outdated packages and the second time when updating packages on this list.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost, If we want to analyse this rigorously ;) let `n` be number of installed packages, and `m` <= `n` number of "outdated" packages.

your's will spin-up `pip` for ALL packages for `1 + n` executions of `pip` with `n*log(n)` web lookups for versions and all dependencies, and `m` downloads and installs.

Mine will do `n` web lookups for the `--outdated` call then will only spinup `m` `pip` calls with `m*log(n)` web lookups for dependencies + `m` download and installs.

for if `m` << `n` I win :)

Comment: @RefaelAckermann Spinning up pip is order of magnitude faster than checking version of a package over network so that's number of checks which should be optimized not number of spin ups. Mine makes n checks, yours makes n+m checks.

Comment: +1 - It's 6.20.2019, I'm using Python 3.7.3 on WIndows 10, and this was the best way for me to update all my local packages.

Comment: Need to skip the first two lines of the output: `for /F "skip=2 delims= " %i in ('pip list --outdated') do pip install --upgrade %i`. If this is run from a batch file, make sure to use `%%i` instead of `%i`. Also note that it's cleaner to update `pip` prior to running this command using `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost I tried your solution for windows 10 but it's not works. here's a [print-screen](https://i.imgur.com/f61KBm1.png)

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη this is for cmd.exe, where the `for` command is built-in. It is not for powershell, where it would be better to use a native looping construct. If you still wanted to use this solution in powershell you would need to invoke cmd.exe explicitly: `cmd /c "for /F ""delims==="" %i in ('pip freeze -l') do pip install -U %i"`

Answer (score 106):

This option seems to me more straightforward and readable:

```bash
pip install -U `pip list --outdated | awk 'NR>2 {print $1}'`
```

---

The explanation is that `pip list --outdated` outputs a list of all the outdated packages in this format:

```
Package   Version Latest Type
--------- ------- ------ -----
fonttools 3.31.0  3.32.0 wheel
urllib3   1.24    1.24.1 wheel
requests  2.20.0  2.20.1 wheel
```

In the [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) command, `NR>2` skips the first two records (lines) and `{print $1}` selects the first word of each line (as suggested by SergioAraujo, I removed `tail -n +3` since `awk` can indeed handle skipping records).

Comment: If one upgrade fails, none of the upgrades happen.

Comment: Use the version from the first answer with `| xargs -n1` to prevent stop on failures

Answer (score 86):

The following one-liner might prove of help:

(pip >= 22.3)

as per [this readable answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27071962/2996101):

```bash
pip install -U `pip list --outdated | awk 'NR>2 {print $1}'`
```

or as per the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3452888/2996101):

```bash
pip --disable-pip-version-check list --outdated --format=json |
    python -c "import json, sys; print('\n'.join([x['name'] for x in json.load(sys.stdin)]))" |
    xargs -n1 pip install -U
```

---

(pip 20.0 < 22.3)

`pip list --format freeze --outdated | sed 's/=.*//g' | xargs -n1 pip install -U`

> Older Versions:
>
> ```
> pip list --format freeze --outdated | sed 's/(.*//g' | xargs -n1 pip install -U
> ```

`xargs -n1` keeps going if an error occurs.

If you need more "fine grained" control over what is omitted and what raises an error you should not add the `-n1` flag and explicitly define the errors to ignore, by "piping" the following line for each separate error:

`| sed 's/^<First characters of the error>.*//'`

Here is a working example:

```bash
pip list --format freeze --outdated | sed 's/=.*//g' | sed 's/^<First characters of the first error>.*//' | sed 's/^<First characters of the second error>.*//' | xargs pip install -U
```

Comment: Had to add filters for lines beginning with 'Could' and 'Some' because apparently pip sends warnings to stdout :(

Comment: OK, this is fair: You can add as many ```| sed 's/^<First characters of the error>.*//'``` as needed. Thank you!

Comment: Or: `pip list --outdated | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | xargs -n 1 pip install --upgrade`

Comment: that works for me, with python3.12 out of the box:

   pip3 list -o | cut -f1 -d' ' | tr " " "\n" | awk '{if(NR>=3)print}' | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs -n1 pip3 install -U

Answer (score 78):

You can just print the packages that are outdated:

```bash
pip freeze | cut -d = -f 1 | xargs -n 1 pip search | grep -B2 'LATEST:'
```

Comment: Inside a virtualenv, I do it like this: `pip freeze --local | cut -d = -f 1 | xargs -n 1 pip search | grep -B2 'LATEST:'`

Comment: Nowadays you can also do that with `python -m pip list outdated` (though it's not in requirements format).

Comment: @Jacktose I think you meant `python -m pip list --outdated`.

Answer (score 74):

**More Robust Solution**

For *pip3*, use this:

```
pip3 freeze --local |sed -rn 's/^([^=# \t\\][^ \t=]*)=.*/echo; echo Processing \1 ...; pip3 install -U \1/p' |sh
```

For *pip*, just remove the 3s as such:

```
pip freeze --local |sed -rn 's/^([^=# \t\\][^ \t=]*)=.*/echo; echo Processing \1 ...; pip install -U \1/p' |sh
```

**OS X Oddity**

OS X, as of July 2017, ships with a very old version of [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) (a dozen years old). To get extended regular expressions, use `-E` instead of `-r` in the solution above.

**Solving Issues with Popular Solutions**

This solution is well designed and tested<sup>1</sup>, whereas there are problems with even the most popular solutions.

- Portability issues due to changing pip command line features
- Crashing of [xargs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) because of common pip or pip3 child process failures
- Crowded logging from the raw *xargs* output
- Relying on a Python-to-OS bridge while potentially upgrading it<sup>3</sup>

The above command uses the simplest and most portable *pip* syntax in combination with *sed* and *sh* to overcome these issues completely. Details of the *sed* operation can be scrutinized with the commented version<sup>2</sup>.

---

**Details**

[1] Tested and regularly used in a Linux 4.8.16-200.fc24.x86_64 cluster and tested on five other Linux/Unix flavors.  It also runs on Cygwin64 installed on Windows 10.  Testing on iOS is needed.

[2] To see the anatomy of the command more clearly, this is the exact equivalent of the above pip3 command with comments:

```
# Match lines from pip's local package list output
# that meet the following three criteria and pass the
# package name to the replacement string in group 1.
# (a) Do not start with invalid characters
# (b) Follow the rule of no white space in the package names
# (c) Immediately follow the package name with an equal sign
sed="s/^([^=# \t\\][^ \t=]*)=.*"

# Separate the output of package upgrades with a blank line
sed="$sed/echo"

# Indicate what package is being processed
sed="$sed; echo Processing \1 ..."

# Perform the upgrade using just the valid package name
sed="$sed; pip3 install -U \1"

# Output the commands
sed="$sed/p"

# Stream edit the list as above
# and pass the commands to a shell
pip3 freeze --local | sed -rn "$sed" | sh
```

[3] Upgrading a Python or PIP component that is also used in the upgrading of a Python or PIP component can be a potential cause of a deadlock or package database corruption.

Comment: another way to overcome the jurassic BSD `sed` of OS X is to use `gsed` (GNU sed) instead. To get it, `brew install gnu-sed`

Comment: @WalterTross ... Jurassic ... good adjective use. So we now have two ways to group update pip packages with a nice audit trail on the terminal. (1) Use the -E option as in the answer and (2) install gsed to leave the Jurassic period.

Answer (score 55):

I had the same problem with upgrading. Thing is, I never upgrade all packages. I upgrade only what I need, because project may break.

Because there was no easy way for upgrading package by package, and updating the requirements.txt file, I wrote this [**pip-upgrader**](https://github.com/simion/pip-upgrader) which **also updates the versions in your `requirements.txt` file** for the packages chosen (or all packages).

#### Installation

```
pip install pip-upgrader
```

#### Usage

Activate your [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) (important, because it will also install the new versions of upgraded packages in current virtualenv).

`cd` into your project directory, then run:

```
pip-upgrade
```

#### Advanced usage

If the requirements are placed in a non-standard location, send them as arguments:

```
pip-upgrade path/to/requirements.txt
```

If you already know what package you want to upgrade, simply send them as arguments:

```
pip-upgrade -p django -p celery -p dateutil
```

If you need to upgrade to pre-release / post-release version, add `--prerelease` argument to your command.

Full disclosure: I wrote this package.

Comment: This is what pip should do by default.

Comment: heads up with your tool some character escapes don't seem to work correctly on my windows machine but other than that it's fine

Comment: haven't really tested it on windows, but i'll install a virtual machine. Thanks

Comment: If `virtualenv` is not enabled `pip-upgrade --skip-virtualenv-check`

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I really like the flow of pip-upgrader. It immediately made a lot of sense to me. Thank you!

Comment: This works also with a requirements folder having common, dev and prod requirements. Simply great!

Answer (score 48):

This seems more concise.

```bash
pip list --outdated | cut -d ' ' -f1 | xargs -n1 pip install -U
```

Explanation:

`pip list --outdated` gets lines like these

```
urllib3 (1.7.1) - Latest: 1.15.1 [wheel]
wheel (0.24.0) - Latest: 0.29.0 [wheel]
```

In `cut -d ' ' -f1`, `-d ' '` sets "space" as the delimiter, `-f1` means to get the first column.

So the above lines becomes:

```
urllib3
wheel
```

Then pass them to `xargs` to run the command, `pip install -U`, with each line as appending arguments.

`-n1` limits the number of arguments passed to each command `pip install -U` to be 1.

Comment: I received this warning `DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.`

Comment: @Reman: that is because you are using Pip v9.0.1. This is just a deprecation message meaning that some functionalities will not survive in a future Pip release. Nothing to be concerned about ;)

Comment: However, this has to be marked as the final solution. Indeed the accepted answer will run all over your pip packages, which is a waste of time if you have to update only 1 or 2 packages. This solution, as instead, will run just all over the outdated packages

Comment: I like this approach except this includes the lines `Package` and `--------------` in the output that'll ultimately be be passed to `pip install -U`. I'm going to post an updated answer with my solution using sed and this approach without the above mentioned issue.

Answer (score 30):

One-liner version of [Ramana's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5839291/3357935).

```
python -c 'import pip, subprocess; [subprocess.call("pip install -U " + d.project_name, shell=1) for d in pip.get_installed_distributions()]'
```

Comment: subprocess.call("sudo pip install... in case you need permissions

Comment: @MaximilianoRios Please do not `sudo pip install`, use a [virtual env](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv), instead.

Answer (score 29):

From *[yolk](https://github.com/cakebread/yolk)*:

```bash
pip install -U `yolk -U | awk '{print $1}' | uniq`
```

However, you need to get yolk first:

```
sudo pip install -U yolk
```

Comment: Last commit 7 years ago

Answer (score 28):

The [`pip_upgrade_outdated`](https://github.com/defjaf/pip_upgrade_outdated) (based on [this older script](https://gist.github.com/serafeimgr/b4ca5d0de63950cc5349d4802d22f3f0)) does the job. According to [its documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pip-upgrade-outdated/):

```
usage: pip_upgrade_outdated [-h] [-3 | -2 | --pip_cmd PIP_CMD]
                            [--serial | --parallel] [--dry_run] [--verbose]
                            [--version]

Upgrade outdated python packages with pip.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  -3                 use pip3
  -2                 use pip2
  --pip_cmd PIP_CMD  use PIP_CMD (default pip)
  --serial, -s       upgrade in serial (default)
  --parallel, -p     upgrade in parallel
  --dry_run, -n      get list, but don't upgrade
  --verbose, -v      may be specified multiple times
  --version          show program's version number and exit
```

Step 1:

```
pip install pip-upgrade-outdated
```

Step 2:

```
pip_upgrade_outdated
```

Comment: Step 1: pip install pip-upgrade-outdated  Step 2: pip-upgrade-outdated  ...done

Comment: This is indeed a really good package. Needs more publicity, I have been working in python for a long while and this is the first time I hear about it. Nice!

Comment: @MarioChapa Thanks -- I wrote it (based on a gist).

Comment: In windows, %USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\envs\bridge\scripts\pip_upgrade_outdated.exe

Answer (score 27):

When using a [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and if you just want to upgrade packages **added** to your virtualenv, you may want to do:

```
pip install `pip freeze -l | cut --fields=1 -d = -` --upgrade
```

Answer (score 27):

#### Updating Python packages on Windows or Linux

1. Output a list of installed packages into a requirements file (requirements.txt):

   ```
   pip freeze > requirements.txt
   ```
2. Edit requirements.txt, and replace all ‘==’ with ‘>=’. Use the ‘Replace All’ command in the editor.
3. Upgrade all outdated packages

   ```
   pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade
   ```

Source: *[How to Update All Python Packages](https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/how-to-update-all-python-packages/)*

Comment: This just works. Just do an `pip freeze > requirements.txt` afterwards to see the acutal diff.

Comment: `pip freeze | sed 's/==/>=/' > requirements.txt` to swap the `==` with `>=` automatically.

Comment: May be good to use another name rather than requirements.txt so you don't accidentally clobber a local requirements.txt from a package.

Answer (score 26):

#### Windows PowerShell solution

```
pip freeze | %{$_.split('==')[0]} | %{pip install --upgrade $_}
```

Comment: `pip list --outdated | %{$_.split('==')[0]} | %{pip install --upgrade $_}`?

Comment: Perhaps `pip list --outdated --format freeze | %{$_.split('==')[0]} | %{pip install --upgrade $_}` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Why is `pip list --outdated --format freeze..` preferred over the suggested answer in Powershell, @brainplot

Comment: @Timo When I wrote that comment the suggested answer only used `pip list` instead of `pip freeze`. I figured `--format freeze` would be more robust against possible changes in future updates than letting `pip list` decide the format. `pip freeze` also works!

Comment: its even better to have it as function in your profile! This is perfect for anyone using powershell

Answer (score 26):

The simplest and fastest solution that I found in the [pip issue discussion](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3819#issuecomment-286696776) is:

```
pip install pipdate
pipdate
```

Source: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3819

Comment: Whereas other solutions stalled upon encountering the slightest anomaly, this solution warned and then skipped the problem to continue with the other packages. Great!

Comment: up voting this, Works perfectly in windows

Comment: I used pipdate and now can't find pip or python. Use at your own risk.

Answer (score 21):

Use [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) update packages:

```bash
pip install -U $(pip freeze | awk -F'[=]' '{print $1}')
```

Windows [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) update

```
foreach($p in $(pip freeze)){ pip install -U $p.Split("=")[0]}
```

Comment: And for python 3... 
pip3 install -U $(pip3 freeze | awk -F'[=]' '{print $1}')

Answer (score 16):

One line in [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) 5.1 with administrator rights, Python 3.6.5, and *pip* version 10.0.1:

```
pip list -o --format json | ConvertFrom-Json | foreach {pip install $_.name -U --no-warn-script-location}
```

It works smoothly if there are no broken packages or special wheels in the list...

Comment: For purely aesthetic reasons, I like this approach the most. The output-producing executable provides our shell the object schema and there is no need for un-labelled index values `[0]` in the script.

Comment: # Set alias for pip upgrade all outdated package
function PipUpgrade-Outdated {
    pip list -o --format json | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object {pip install $_.name -U}
}

Comment: something similar in Ubutun, e.g., if using WSL2, would be `pip list --outdated --format json | jq '.[].name' | xargs -i pip install {} -U`

Answer (score 15):

You can try this:

```bash
for i in `pip list | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}'`; do pip install --upgrade $i; done
```

Comment: this is the cleanest, highest readable way to update pip packages in the most amount of brevity. great.

Answer (score 14):

If you have `pip<22.3` installed, a pure [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29)/[Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) one-liner for achieving that:

```bash
for p in $(pip list -o --format freeze); do pip install -U ${p%%=*}; done
```

Or, in a nicely-formatted way:

```bash
for p in $(pip list -o --format freeze)
do
    pip install -U ${p%%=*}
done
```

After this you will have `pip>=22.3`  in which `-o` and `--format freeze` are mutually exclusive, and you can no longer use this one-liner.

Comment: What does <p%%=*> stand for?

Comment: @ᐅdevrimbaris this removes version spec and leaves only package name. You can see it by running `for p in $(pip list -o --format freeze); do echo "${p} -> ${p%%=*}"; done`. In more general way, `${haystack%%needle}` means `delete longest match of needle from back of haystack`.

Answer (score 13):

The rather amazing yolk makes this easy.

```
pip install yolk3k # Don't install `yolk`, see https://github.com/cakebread/yolk/issues/35
yolk --upgrade
```

For more information on yolk: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yolk/0.4.3

It can do lots of things you'll probably find useful.

Answer (score 11):

Use:

```
pip install -r <(pip freeze) --upgrade
```

Answer (score 11):

The shortest and easiest on Windows.

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt && pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt && rm requirements.txt
```

Comment: @Enkouyami on windows 7 this command does not work without the -r. -r must preclude the path to the requirements file.

Comment: In what context? CMD? [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell)? [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin)? [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution))? Something else?

Answer (score 11):

There is not necessary to be so troublesome or install some package.

Update pip packages on **Linux shell**:

```bash
pip list --outdated --format=freeze | awk -F"==" '{print $1}' | xargs -i pip install -U {}
```

Update pip packages on **Windows powershell**:

```
pip list --outdated --format=freeze | ForEach { pip install -U $_.split("==")[0] }
```

Some points:

- Replace `pip` as your python version to `pip3` or `pip2`.
- `pip list --outdated` to check outdated pip packages.
- `--format` on my pip version 22.0.3 only has 3 types: *columns (default), freeze, or json*. `freeze` is better option in command pipes.
- Keep command *simple and usable* as many systems as possible.

Comment: Thank you for the PowerShell snippet, this was the most useful answer for me!

Comment: On pip3 it fails with: `ERROR: List format 'freeze' cannot be used with the --outdated option.`

Answer (score 10):

[Ramana's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5839291/3357935) worked the best for me, of those here, but I had to add a few catches:

```
import pip
for dist in pip.get_installed_distributions():
    if 'site-packages' in dist.location:
        try:
            pip.call_subprocess(['pip', 'install', '-U', dist.key])
        except Exception, exc:
            print exc
```

The `site-packages` check excludes my development packages, because they are not located in the system site-packages directory. The try-except simply skips packages that have been removed from PyPI.

[To endolith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/how-to-upgrade-all-python-packages-with-pip#comment12158624_5839291): I was hoping for an easy `pip.install(dist.key, upgrade=True)`, too, but it doesn't look like pip was meant to be used by anything but the command line (the docs don't mention the internal API, and the pip developers didn't use docstrings).

Comment: On Ubuntu (and other Debian derivatives), `pip` apparently puts packages in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` or similar. You could use '/usr/local/lib/' instead of 'site-packages' in the `if` statement in this case.

Answer (score 10):

Sent through [a pull-request to the pip folks](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/1506); in the meantime use this pip library solution I wrote:

```
from operator import attrgetter

## Old solution:
# from pip import get_installed_distributions
# from pip.commands import install
## New solution:
from pkg_resources import working_set
from pip._internal.commands import install    

install_cmd = install.InstallCommand()

options, args = install_cmd.parse_args(
    ## Old solution:
    # list(map(attrgetter("project_name")
    #          get_installed_distributions()))
    ## New solution:
    list(map(attrgetter("project_name"), working_set))
)

options.upgrade = True
install_cmd.run(options, args)  # Chuck this in a try/except and print as wanted
```

Comment: Version with error handling (as per comment): https://gist.github.com/SamuelMarks/7885f2e8e5f0562b1063

Comment: On pip3 there is no such function as `get_installed_distributions`

Comment: @areop-enap - For at least a little while, this will work instead: `install_cmd.parse_args(list(map(attrgetter("project_name"), working_set)))` - I'll edit this answer

Answer (score 10):

This ought to be more effective:

```bash
pip3 list -o | grep -v -i warning | cut -f1 -d' ' | tr " " "\n" | awk '{if(NR>=3)print}' | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs -n1 pip3 install -U
```

1. `pip list -o` lists outdated packages;
2. `grep -v -i warning` inverted match on `warning` to avoid errors when updating
3. `cut -f1 -d1' '` returns the first word - the name of the outdated package;
4. `tr "\n|\r" " "` converts the multiline result from `cut` into a single-line, space-separated list;
5. `awk '{if(NR>=3)print}'` skips header lines
6. `cut -d' ' -f1` fetches the first column
7. `xargs -n1 pip install -U` takes 1 argument from the pipe left of it, and passes it to the command to upgrade the list of packages.

Comment: Here's my output: `kerberos iwlib PyYAML Could pygpgme Could Could Could ...`
Note all the "Could"s. Those stem from output of `pip list -o` of "Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement <package>"

Comment: Comments don't format this well, but here's a snippet (line endings are marked with ';'): `# pip list -o;
urwid (Current: 1.1.1 Latest: 1.3.0);
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement python-default-encoding;
pycups (Current: 1.9.63 Latest: 1.9.68);
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement policycoreutils-default-encoding;
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement sepolicy;
`

Comment: instead of filtering out all lines which shouldn't be used, I would suggest to filter the lines where an update exists: `pip install -U $(pip list -o | grep -i current | cut -f1 -d' ' | tr  "\n|\r" " ") ` . Otherwise you could easily miss one line you don't want and get the result which DrStrangeprk mentioned.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using `xargs` instead. `pip list -o | awk '/Current:/ {print $1}' | xargs -rp -- pip install -U` The `-r` flag ensures that `pip install -U` won't be run if there are no outdated packages. The `-p` flag prompts the user to confirm before executing any command. You can add the `-n1` flag to have it prompt you prior to installing each package separately.

Answer (score 10):

This is a PowerShell solution for Python 3:

```
pip3 list --outdated --format=legacy | ForEach { pip3 install -U $_.split(" ")[0] }
```

And for Python 2:

```
pip2 list --outdated --format=legacy | ForEach { pip2 install -U $_.split(" ")[0] }
```

This upgrades the packages one by one. So a

```
pip3 check
pip2 check
```

afterwards should make sure no dependencies are broken.

Comment: At least with pip>=22.3, legacy is no longer an available format

Answer (score 9):

This seemed to work for me...

```bash
pip install -U $(pip list --outdated | awk '{printf $1" "}')
```

I used `printf` with a space afterwards to properly separate the package names.

Answer (score 7):

A JSON + [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) answer:

```bash
pip list -o --format json | jq '.[] | .name' | xargs pip install -U
```

Comment: the `jq` filtering can be further simplified to `jq -c '.[].name'`

Answer (score 6):

See all outdated packages

```
pip list --outdated --format=columns
```

Install

```
sudo pip install pipdate
```

then type

```
sudo -H pipdate
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's the code for updating all Python 3 packages (in the activated `virtualenv`) via pip:

```
import pkg_resources
from subprocess import call

for dist in pkg_resources.working_set:
    call("python3 -m pip install --upgrade " + dist.project_name, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is my variation on [rbp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/how-to-upgrade-all-python-packages-with-pip/3452888#3452888), which bypasses "editable" and development distributions. It shares two flaws of the original: it re-downloads and reinstalls unnecessarily; and an error on one package will prevent the upgrade of every package after that.

```
pip freeze |sed -ne 's/==.*//p' |xargs pip install -U --
```

Related bug reports, a bit disjointed after the migration from Bitbucket:

- https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/49
- https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/59

Answer (score 5):

Here is a script that only updates the outdated packages.

```
import os, sys
from subprocess import check_output, call

file = check_output(["pip.exe",  "list", "--outdated", "--format=legacy"])
line = str(file).split()

for distro in line[::6]:
    call("pip install --upgrade " + distro, shell=True)
```

For a new version of pip that does not output as a legacy format (version 18+):

```
import os, sys
from subprocess import check_output, call

file = check_output(["pip.exe", "list", "-o", "--format=json"])
line = str(file).split()

for distro in line[1::8]:
    distro = str(distro).strip('"\",')
    call("pip install --upgrade " + distro, shell=True)
```

Comment: That sadly no longer works. pip --format does not accept "legacy" as a choice. At least not on my python release.

Comment: @StormShadow as you hope know, pip really poorly control depencies. it does exactly as other solution - yep(( Better to add disclaimer

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
import pip
pkgs = [p.key for p in pip.get_installed_distributions()]
for pkg in pkgs:
    pip.main(['install', '--upgrade', pkg])
```

Or even:

```
import pip
commands = ['install', '--upgrade']
pkgs = commands.extend([p.key for p in pip.get_installed_distributions()])
pip.main(commands)
```

It works fast as it is not constantly launching a shell.

Comment: Does constantly launching a shell really make a measurable difference when we'll end up downloading packages from pypi followed by (compilation and) installation?

Comment: @gerrit I my experience yes it does, especially in an environment where you have aggressive anti-virus software that you can't turn off running. Where I work we cannot disable or suppress the AV and each shell launch takes 20-30 seconds but, on good days, we do have a fast internet connection. When you are installing large packages the installation time can be significant but when it is a lot of smaller package the shell start time is very significant.

Answer (score 5):

I've been using [pur](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pur) lately. It's simple and to the point. It updates your `requirements.txt` file to reflect the upgrades and you can then upgrade with your `requirements.txt` file as usual.

```
$ pip install pur
...
Successfully installed pur-4.0.1

$ pur
Updated boto3: 1.4.2 -> 1.4.4
Updated Django: 1.10.4 -> 1.10.5
Updated django-bootstrap3: 7.1.0 -> 8.1.0
All requirements up-to-date.

$ pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt
Successfully installed Django-1.10.5 ...
```

Answer (score 5):

The below Windows `cmd` snippet does the following:

> - Upgrades `pip` to latest version.

- Upgrades all outdated packages.
- For each packages being upgraded checks `requirements.txt` for any version specifiers.

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/

echo Upgrading pip...
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
echo.

echo Upgrading packages...
set upgrade_count=0
pip list --outdated > pip-upgrade-outdated.txt
for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,3 delims= " %%i in (pip-upgrade-outdated.txt) do (
    echo ^>%%i
    set package=%%i
    set latest=%%j
    set requirements=!package!

    rem for each outdated package check for any version requirements:
    set dotest=1
    for /F %%r in (.\python\requirements.txt) do (
        if !dotest!==1 (
            call :substr "%%r" !package! _substr
            rem check if a given line refers to a package we are about to upgrade:
            if "%%r" NEQ !_substr! (
                rem check if the line contains more than just a package name:
                if "%%r" NEQ "!package!" (
                    rem set requirements to the contents of the line:
                    echo requirements: %%r, latest: !latest!
                    set requirements=%%r
                )
                rem stop testing after the first instance found,
                rem prevents from mistakenly matching "py" with "pylint", "numpy" etc.
                rem requirements.txt must be structured with shorter names going first
                set dotest=0
            )
        )
    )
    rem pip install !requirements!
    pip install --upgrade !requirements!
    set /a "upgrade_count+=1"
    echo.
)

if !upgrade_count!==0 (
    echo All packages are up to date.
) else (
    type pip-upgrade-outdated.txt
)

if "%1" neq "-silent" (
    echo.
    set /p temp="> Press Enter to exit..."
)
exit /b


:substr
rem string substition done in a separate subroutine -
rem allows expand both variables in the substring syntax.
rem replaces str_search with an empty string.
rem returns the result in the 3rd parameter, passed by reference from the caller.
set str_source=%1
set str_search=%2
set str_result=!str_source:%str_search%=!
set "%~3=!str_result!"
rem echo !str_source!, !str_search!, !str_result!
exit /b
```

Comment: @ScamCast Glad you liked it! I've just updated the snipped to the latest version I'm using.

Comment: `for /F "skip=2" %G in ('pip list --outdated') do pip install %G --upgrade` should do the job as well however preceding `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`  isn't a bad idea:)

Answer (score 4):

I have tried [the code of Ramana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/how-to-upgrade-all-python-packages-with-pip/5839291#5839291) and I found out on Ubuntu you have to write `sudo` for each command. Here is my script which works fine on [Ubuntu 13.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_13.10_.28Saucy_Salamander.29) (Saucy Salamander):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pip
from subprocess import call

for dist in pip.get_installed_distributions():
    call("sudo pip install --upgrade " + dist.project_name, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way of doing with a script in Python:

```
import pip, tempfile, contextlib

with tempfile.TemporaryFile('w+') as temp:
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(temp):
        pip.main(['list', '-o'])
    temp.seek(0)
    for line in temp:
        pk = line.split()[0]
        print('--> updating', pk, '<--')
        pip.main(['install', '-U', pk])
```

Answer (score 4):

One liner (bash). Shortest, easiest, for me.

```
pip install -U $(pip freeze | cut -d = -f 1)
```

Explanations:

- `pip freeze` returns `package_name==version` for each package
- `cut -d = -f 1` means "for each line, return the 1st line's field where fields are delimited by `=`"
- `$(cmd)` returns the result of command `cmd`. So here, `cmd` will return the list of package names and `pip install -U` will upgrade them.

Comment: I find this syntax more readable: `pip install --upgrade \`pip freeze | cut -d '=' -f 1\``.

Comment: That's the same, it's just bash syntax preferences, not command changes

Answer (score 3):

```
import os
import pip
from subprocess import call, check_call

pip_check_list = ['pip', 'pip3']
pip_list = []
FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')


for s_pip in pip_check_list:
    try:
        check_call([s_pip, '-h'], stdout=FNULL)
        pip_list.append(s_pip)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass


for dist in pip.get_installed_distributions():
    for pip in pip_list:
        call("{0} install --upgrade ".format(pip) + dist.project_name, shell=True)
```

I took [Ramana's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5839291/3357935) and made it pip3 friendly.

Answer (score 3):

As another answer here stated:

```
pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1 | xargs -n1 pip install -U
```

Is a possible solution: Some comments here, myself included, had issues with permissions while using this command. A little change to the following solved those for me.

```
pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1 | xargs -n1 sudo -H pip install -U
```

Note the added `sudo -H` which allowed the command to run with root permissions.

To upgrade only outdated versions on a local / user environment for pip3

```
pip3 install --user -U `pip3 list -ol --format=json|grep -Po 'name": "\K.*?(?=")'`
```

The switch `-ol` works similar to `--outdated --local` or `-o --user`. On Debian Testing you might also add the switch `--break-system-packages` to install command. But do that only on your own risk. This command might be useful on super up-to-date systems where AI runs and anything with root is avoided. It helps porting from Stable Diffusion 1.5 to 2.1 with rocm support for example.

Comment: Use the first version with a virtual environment and the second (```sudo -H```) version when updating the packages for your whole system.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on macOS,

1. make sure you have [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) installed
2. install [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) in order to read the JSON you’re about to generate

```sh
brew install jq
```

3. update each item on the list of outdated packages generated by `pip3 list --outdated`

```sh
pip3 install --upgrade  `pip3 list --outdated --format json | jq '.[] | .name' | awk -F'"' '{print $2}'`
```

Comment: Works for linux as well, given `jq` is universal (and already installed).

Comment: the following also works fine `pip list --outdated --format json | jq '.[].name' | xargs -i pip install {} -U`

Answer (score 2):

One line in cmd:

```
for /F "delims= " %i in ('pip list --outdated --format=legacy') do pip install -U %i
```

So a

`pip check`

afterwards should make sure no dependencies are broken.

Answer (score 2):

I use this one liner set up as an alias to upgrade my pip3 packages:

```bash
pip3 list --outdated | sed '1,2d; s/ .*//' | xargs -n1 pip3 install -U
```

or alternatively

```bash
pip3 list --outdated | tail -n +3 | cut -d ' ' -f1 | xargs -n1 pip3 install -U
```

(note that while it's most likely the case these aliases will work with most shells, you're shell will have to support either pip, sed, and xargs for the first alias or pip, tail, cut, and xargs for the 2nd alias which come preinstalled on most nix/nix-like systems)

1. `pip3 list --outdated` gets a list of installed outdated pip3 packages:

```bash
$ pip3 list --outdated
Package        Version Latest Type
-------------- ------- ------ -----
dbus-python    1.2.18  1.3.2  sdist
pycairo        1.20.1  1.25.1 sdist
PyGObject      3.42.1  3.46.0 sdist
systemd-python 234     235    sdist
```

2. `sed '1,2d; s/ .*//'` or `tail -n +3 | cut -d ' ' -f1` removes the first 2 lines of output and all characters inclusively after the first space character for each remaining line:

```bash
pip3 list --outdated | sed '1,2d; s/ .*//'
# pip3 list --outdated | tail -n +3 | cut -d ' ' -f1
dbus-python
pycairo
PyGObject
systemd-python
```

3. `xargs -n1 pip3 install -U` passes the name of each package as an argument to `pip3 install -U` (pip command to recursively upgrade all packages).

I ran some benchmarks and `sed` appeared to be faster on my system. I used`sed` and then `tail` and `cut` to edit a text file input 5000 times and timed it. Here are the results:

```
sed:
------------------
real    0m9.188s
user    0m6.217s
sys 0m3.232s

tail-cut:
------------------
real    0m12.869s
user    0m13.913s
sys 0m9.921s
```

The benchmark setup can be found in the gist -> [HERE](https://gist.github.com/SnapperGee/ef96ede9bccb35b103bf14d973833da1) <-

Answer (score 1):

*for* in a bat script:

```
call pip freeze > requirements.txt
call powershell "(Get-Content requirements.txt) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '==', '>=' } | Set-Content requirements.txt"
call pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade all of your pip default packages in your default Python version, just run the below Python code in your terminal or command prompt:

```
import subprocess
import re

pkg_list = subprocess.getoutput('pip freeze')

pkg_list = pkg_list.split('\n')

new_pkg = []
for i in pkg_list:
    re.findall(r"^(.*)==.*", str(i))
    new = re.findall(r"^(.*)==.*", str(i))[0]
    new_pkg.append(new)

for i in new_pkg:
    print(subprocess.getoutput('pip install '+str(i)+' --upgrade'))
```

Answer (score 1):

1. By using *pip-upgrader*

   - using this library you can easily upgrade all the dependencies packages. These are set up you follows.

     ```
     pip install pip-upgrader

     pip-upgrade path/of/requirements_txt_file
     ```

An interactive pip requirements upgrader. Because upgrading requirements, package by package, is a pain in the ass. It also updates the version in your *requirements.txt* file.

Answer (score 1):

Use pipx instead:

```
pipx upgrade-all
```

Comment: What is this "pipx" you speak of? E.g., can you add some references? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74425440/edit), not here in comments (******** ***without*** ******** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: `pip3 upgrade-all` leads to `ERROR: unknown command "upgrade-all"` I guess that command is removed again

Comment: https://pypa.github.io/pipx/

Answer (score 1):

```bash
pip install --upgrade `pip list --format=freeze | cut -d '=' -f 1`
```

`pip list --format=freeze` includes `pip` and `setuptools`. `pip freeze` does not.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74988130.

Answer (score 0):

If you want upgrade only packaged installed by pip, and to avoid upgrading packages that are installed by other tools (like apt, yum etc.), then you can use this script that I use on my Ubuntu (maybe works also on other distros) - based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49670365/1961303):

```bash
printf "To update with pip: pip install -U"
pip list --outdated 2>/dev/null | gawk '{print $1;}' | while read; do pip show "${REPLY}" 2>/dev/null | grep 'Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages' >/dev/null; if (( $? == 0 )); then printf " ${REPLY}"; fi; done; echo
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use pip-tools to handle this process.

Package pip-tools presents two scripts:

pip-compile: used to create a viable *requirements.txt* from a *requirement.in* file.
pip-sync: used to sync the local environment pip repository to match that of your *requirements.txt* file.

If I want to upgrade a particular package say:

django==3.2.12

to

django==3.2.16

I can then change the base version of Django in *requirements.in*, run pip-compile and then run pip-sync. This will effectively upgrade django (and all dependent packages too) by removing older versions and then installing new versions.

It is very simple to use for upgrades in addition to pip package maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to upgrade packages installed in `/opt/...` virtual environments:

```
( pip=/opt/SOMEPACKAGE/bin/pip; "$pip" install -U $("$pip" list -o | sed -n -e '1,2d; s/[[:space:]].*//p') )
```

(unrelated tip, if you need shell variables, run commands inside a `( ... )` subshell so as to not pollute)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `venv`, where you don't need to use `sudo`:

```
$ pip list --outdated --format=json \
    | jq -r '.[].name' \
    | xargs -n1 pip install -U
```

**Explanation**

1. `pip list --outdated --format=json`

Returns JSON-formatted list of all outdated packages

2. `jq -r '.[].name'`

Extracts `name` from JSON output

3. `xargs -n1 pip install -U`

Upgrades all Python packages one by one

Answer (score 0):

That works for me for Python 3.12 out of the box, directly or in a virtual envornment:

```
pip3 list -o | cut -f1 -d' ' | tr " " "\n" | awk '{if(NR>=3)print}' | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs -n1 pip3 install -U
```

Answer (score -1):

```
python -c 'import pip; [pip.main(["install", "--upgrade", d.project_name]) for d in pip.get_installed_distributions()]'
```

One liner!

Comment: On pip3 I get this error: `AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'get_installed_distributions'`

Answer (score -1):

All posted solutions here break dependencies.

From [this conversation](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4551#issuecomment-1172013608) to include the functionality directly into pip, including properly managing dependencies:

The author of *[Meta Package Manager](https://github.com/kdeldycke/meta-package-manager)* (MPM) writes that MPM can [emulate the missing upgrade-all](https://kdeldycke.github.io/meta-package-manager/usecase.html#extra-features-for-your-package-managers) command:

```
mpm --pip upgrade --all
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"break dependencies"*? Can you elaborate?

Comment: You run update and then you end up with version conflicts, that's what breaking dependencies means. But it turns out MPM does the same, despite the author promising diffently.

Answer (score -1):

```
pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1 | xargs -n1 pip install -U
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

Another alternative to updating pip packages is:

```
pip install --upgrade $(pip freeze | cut -d '=' -f 1)
```

or

```
python -m pip install --upgrade $(pip freeze | cut -d '=' -f 1)
```

You can also use:

```
// python2

pip2 install --upgrade $(pip freeze | cut -d '=' -f 1)
python2 -m pip install --upgrade $(pip freeze | cut -d '=' -f 1) 

// python3 
pip3 install --upgrade $(pip freeze | cut -d '=' -f 1)
python3 -m pip install --upgrade $(pip freeze | cut -d '=' -f 1)
```

These commands will update all pip packages.

Comment: Would you please explain what these do, and how they're different? Copying and pasting commands without understanding what they do is a problem in this industry.

Comment: What they do is update all the python packages you have, the commands are alternatives for the different versions of python, for example 2.x.x, 3.x.x and the pip version goes with python.

Comment: You've given _six different_ commands. And there are already several answers to this question. Again, please clarify what each one of them does and how they're different from each other, and from answers that are already here. See [answer].

Comment: Again they are commands to update Python programming language packages, they do the same thing but in different ways, if you don't understand the programming language you won't understand it.

Comment: I'll ask a different way: Why are there _six_ of them? How should users decide which one to run? And are you _sure_ that these are distinct from all of the other answers that are already here?

Comment: You must understand that these six are alternatives, you can use them by checking your version of python and if it works, otherwise I would not publish it, something that must be understood, the programmer is never limited to a single option.

Comment: "the programmer is never limited to a single option"—this question has _81 answers_.

Comment: You're completely missing the point