# Python configparser error after Yosemite install

Tags: python, osx-yosemite, configparser

I've upgraded to Yosemite and this seems to have broken my python modules.

`python --version` == `Python 2.7.6`

Then from the Python shell:

```
>>> import pyrax
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyrax/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import six.moves.configparser as ConfigParser
ImportError: No module named configparser
```

So its complaining about `configparser`.

```
pip show configparser
---
Name: configparser
Version: 3.3.0r2
Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requires:
```

But it is there. After some reading it seems clear that ConfigParser has been renamed to configparser in python version 3. I am however running 2.7.

--- EDIT ----

Some more info:
I'm **not** using homebrew for Python
I've tried re-installing pyrax

Any ideas ?

Comment: I also had broken packages when upgrading from Mountain Lion to Mavericks. If I remember right, I had to reinstall almost all 3rd party packages (mostly via `pip`) to get them to work again. Because of your question, I am now wondering exactly when Apple will get this whole upgrading thing working smoothly.

Comment: Running out of options I decided to give this a go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/upgrading-all-packages-with-pip . Unfortunately no luck there.

Answer (score 9):

Just move the old six out of the way, and reinstall via pip...

```
mkdir ~/six-old-library/
mkdir ~/six-old-system-library/
sudo mv /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/six* ~/six-old-library/
sudo mv /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six* ~/six-old-system-library/
sudo pip install six
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and spent a couple of hours investigating it.
I learned that the default python for OS X 10.10 contains an outdated `six` package.

This is how I fixed it:

1. Install the `python` package from homebrew:

   ```
   brew install python
   ```

   Make sure that homebrew python is your default system version.  Check brew doctor and your default `$PATH`:

   ```
   brew doctor
   ```

   Should say "Your system is ready to brew." If it doesn't, you need to fix it first.  We need to use homebrew's python, not OS X's python:

   ```
   which python
   ```

   Should output and point to "/usr/local/bin/python"

   If it doesn't, check your `$PATH` - it should output "/usr/local/bin" first, then "/usr/bin". If it doesn't, update it in `.bash_profile` and/or `.zshrc`.
2. Uninstall all your python packages:

   ```
   pip freeze | grep -v "^-e" | xargs pip uninstall -y
   ```
3. Reinstall all your python packages as needed:

   ```
   pip install -r requirements.txt
   ```

After all that, it should work.