# Import Error: DependencyWarning with every pip install attempt

Tags: python, pip

I'm a mac user and installing with pip used to work. However I did something and now it doesn't work anymore. When running `pip install somepackagename`, I get the error `ImportError: cannot import name DependencyWarning`. I pasted the entire error below for trying to install PyPDF2.

For as far as I understand it the error is something with the `requests` module. I tried to uninstall it running pip uninstall requests, which results in the same error. Uninstalling other packages as well.

Anybody got an idea what's going wrong?

The error when installing PyPDF2

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Arno/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==7.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/Users/Arno/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 558, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/Users/Arno/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2682, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/Users/Arno/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2355, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/Users/Arno/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2361, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/Users/Arno/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
ImportError: cannot import name DependencyWarning
```

Comment: I think what you did was you install Enthought, and it has taken over as your default Python interpreter - with a very outdated version of `pip`. Try upgrading pip, with `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: When trying to upgrade I get the exact same error.

Comment: Try pip install --upgrade requests

Comment: `DependencyWarning` seems to be required by `requests` through `urllib3.exceptions`. try upgrading those packages first, then try upgrading everything in pip. Hopefully, after this experience, you'll gain more respect for virtual environments or containers :P

Comment: No respect yet... So DependencyWarning is a separate package. However urllib3.exceptions is a package within requests. Right? And I have to update urllib3.exceptions within requests. However Trying to update either requests or urllib3.exceptions results in the same error. I tried updating every package I have (using the python code from the second answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/upgrading-all-packages-with-pip) ) which resulted in a whole list of the same errors.

Comment: I eventually solved this by removing python entirely and reinstalling it...