# Jupyter crash after modules update

Tags: python, pip, jupyter

I tried to update my python modules using [this command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5839291/8105686):

```
$ pip install pip-review
$ pip-review --local --interactive
```

Since then, I cannot run any of my IPython notebooks (Jupyter always tells me that my kernels are dead, Spyder doesn't open anymore). Jupyter returns me with:

> ImportError: No module named shutil_get_terminal_size.

I am using Python 2.7.12 and Anaconda 4.2.0.

I am a student and am not very familiar with the technical side, so please take that into consideration.

Comment: If you use `conda` you probably shouldn't try to keep track of your packages with `pip-review`. The packages from `pip` might not be binary-compatible with those from `conda`.

Comment: How exactly can I fix the situation? Do I need to reinstall?

Comment: That depends on your state. Personally I would just create [a new `conda` environment](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html) and use that. But I'm not sure it's possible.