# powershell to run pip

Tags: python, powershell, pip

I want to run python modules upgrades vie powershell script.
   First line works.
   But I do not know how to read the file correctly into
   the second pip line.  I get this error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Get-Content   

pip freeze| Out-File requirements.txt 
pip install --upgrade  Get-Content requirements.txt
Remove-Item  requirements.txt
```

UPDATE: Works now with changed second line.

```
    pip freeze| Out-File requirements.txt 

    foreach($line in Get-Content requirements.txt) 
    {
      pip install --upgrade $line 
    }  

    Remove-Item  requirements.txt
```

UPDATE 2  Now with python 3.6 I use this script.

```
$(
$exclude = 'virtualenv', 'prompt-toolkit'
pip list --outdated --format=freeze  | ForEach{ $_.split("=")[0]} | Where-Object { $exclude -notcontains $_ } | ForEach { pip install -U $_ }                               
) *>&1 >> Python_Modules_Updates_Log.txt
```

Comment: Add brackets around your get-content? pip install --upgrade ( Get-Content requirements.txt )

Comment: @OwainEsau, with brackets it does run without errors, but upgrades did not happen. Does ( Get-Content requirements.txt ) emulate the -r on the command line, that is -r requirements.txt ?

Comment: Are there multiple lines in this text file? because if there is, it would be much better with a foreach loop for each line.

Comment: And i just saw the update

Comment: see also [Upgrading all packages with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51022937/8275142)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve your goal:

```
pip freeze | ForEach-Object { pip install --upgrade $_ }
```

Each output line from `pip freeze` is passed through the pipeline, and the `ForEach-Object` script block invokes `pip install --upgrade` for each (`$_`).

---

As for **what you tried**:

```
pip install --upgrade  Get-Content requirements.txt # !! BROKEN
```

`Get-Content` and `requirements.txt` are simply additional arguments passed to `pip`, which explains the error message you saw.

`pip` - without `-r` - only accepts *one* package (requirements specifier) at a time, so even something like `pip install --upgrade (Get-Content requirements.txt)` would *not* have worked (it would have passed the lines of file `requirements.txt` as *individual arguments*).

With `-r`, a *filename* argument is required, so you could have tried:

```
pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt
```

Note that PowerShell, as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core v6.0.2, does *not* support Bash-style process substitutions, where a command's output can act as a transient *file*:

```
pip install --upgrade -r <(pip freeze) # !! WISHFUL THINKING - does NOT work yet
```

However, such a [feature is being considered](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4284).