# setup.py egg_info error code 3221225477

Tags: python, machine-learning, yolo

I've been trying to install `IMGAUG` package for an ML project. But the installation gets stuck when it tries to install `scikit-image`

My input: `pip install scikit-image`

output:

```
Collecting imgaug
Using cached 
https://files.pythonhosted.org/...
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in 
c:\users\*<username>*\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site- 
packages (from imgaug) (1.1.0)
Collecting scikit-image>=0.11.0 (from imgaug)
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/...
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 3221225477 in 
C:\Users\<name>~1.<name2>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qmdp6ysz\scikit-image\
```

Note: I've already tried installing other versions of it, upgrading setuptools and pip. Error persists.

PS: Now it's showing up on everything I try to install.

Comment: This line is not enough, please give your command and full output.

Comment: There is no package `scikit`. You probably mean `scikit-image`?

Comment: yes, scikit-image.

Comment: Is this really the complete output? `Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/...` is unlikely to be the whole line. And is there really nothing between `Complete output...` and `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed` ?

Comment: yeah this is the entire output, I copied and pasted the entire thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>(Scroll down to a horizontal line to skip explanation and go straight to the suggested solution if you wish)</sub>

`3221225477` is `0xC0000005` [which is `NTSTATUS` `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx); the corresponsing error message is `The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.`.

[In Windows, a process usually quits with this exit code if it tries to access an invalid memory address and Windows terminates it as a result](https://github.com/stan-dev/pystan/issues/317). If you install Visual Studio, you'll be able to pinpoint the exact module at fault as shown on the link.

Now, this error means a bug in or an incompatibility between some of your installed extension modules (or in Python engine itself, but this is very unlikely in comparison).

The easiest way to fix is to clean up any problems with the involved modules' installation and (if that isn't enough) update them to the latest versions, hoping that whatever is causing that is fixed in them.

- In particular, `scipy in c:\users\*<username>*\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages` looks suspicious: you aren't using [`--user`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-user) in your `pip` command

  - which suggests that your didn't pay attention to this flag when using `pip` before ([it's official that it CAN lead to version conflicts](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#user-installs)), and some of your installed packages are installed both into `%ProgramFiles%\Python37\Lib\site-packages` and `%APPDATA%\Python\Python37\ib\site-packages`, with different versions in these two locations.

---

I hereby suggest you to:

- decide where you want your 3rd-party modules to be

  - `%ProgramFiles%` is system-wide and requires elevation to manage, `%APPDATA%` is per-user and doesn't require elevation
  - Unless you don't have administrative rights at your machine (you do, judging by the command you gave) or have special needs, keep everything in the system-wide location for simplicity
- uninstall all the modules in the other location (`pip uninstall <name(s)>` with or without `--user`)
- reinstall them to the desired location, updating existing versions (`-U` pip flag)
- if that wasn't enough to solve the problem (very unlikely), [update all packages to the latest versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/upgrading-all-packages-with-pip)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me also. However I resolved it by uninstalling the package (pip uninstall ), then installing it using conda rather than pip (conda install ).