# setup.py install for mayavi error code 3221225477

Tags: python, cmd, pip, mayavi

I've been trying to install `mayavi` package. But I get the following Error Code:

Input:
`pip install mayavi`

Output:

```
  Using cached mayavi-4.7.1.tar.bz2 (7.0 MB) 
Requirement already satisfied: apptools in c:\users\[user]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from mayavi) (4.5.0) 
Requirement already satisfied: envisage in c:\users\[user]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from mayavi) (4.9.2) 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\[user]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from mayavi) (1.19.0) 
Requirement already satisfied: pyface>=6.1.1 in c:\users\[user]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from mayavi) (7.0.0) 
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in c:\users\[user]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from mayavi) (2.6.1) 
Requirement already satisfied: traits>=4.6.0 in c:\users\[user]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from mayavi) (6.1.0) 
Requirement already satisfied: traitsui>=6.0.0 in c:\users\[user]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from mayavi) (7.0.0) 
Requirement already satisfied: vtk in c:\users\[user]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from mayavi) (9.0.1) 
Requirement already satisfied: configobj in c:\users\[user]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from apptools->mayavi) (5.0.6) 
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\[user]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from apptools->mayavi) (1.15.0) 
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\[user]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from envisage->mayavi) (49.1.0) 
Building wheels for collected packages: mayavi 
  Building wheel for mayavi (setup.py) ... error 
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 3221225477: 
   command: 'c:\users\[user]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9m9ho30d\\mayavi\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9m9ho30d\\mayavi\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-nbag40lo' 
       cwd: C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9m9ho30d\mayavi\ 
  Complete output (4 lines): 
  running bdist_wheel 
  running build 
---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Building TVTK classes... 
  ---------------------------------------- 
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mayavi 
  Running setup.py clean for mayavi 
Failed to build mayavi 
Installing collected packages: mayavi 
    Running setup.py install for mayavi ... error 
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 3221225477: 
     command: 'c:\users\[user]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9m9ho30d\\mayavi\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9m9ho30d\\mayavi\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-y6i7mpay\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\[user]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\mayavi' 
         cwd: C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9m9ho30d\mayavi\ 
    Complete output (4 lines): 
    running install 
    running build 
---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    Building TVTK classes... 
    ---------------------------------------- 
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 3221225477: 'c:\users\[user]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9m9ho30d\\mayavi\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\[user]\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9m9ho30d\\mayavi\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-y6i7mpay\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\[user]\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\mayavi' Check the logs for full command output.
```

In an older question ([setup.py egg_info error code 3221225477](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51816639/setup-py-egg-info-error-code-3221225477)) I found out that this "error means a bug in or an incompatibility between some of my installed extension modules".
But I made sure, that all my extensions are installed only in per-user and not system-wide directory.

I also updated all packages to the latest version.

EDIT:

- I installed Python 3.7 (previously it was 3.8) but the error persists.
- I tried it with a Windows Subsystem for Linux but still got the same error
- I finally solved it by using conda with Python 3.7

Comment: **NT Status** 0xC0000005 (-1073741819 or 3221225477) **Windows Error** 0x3E6 (998) **NT Status Message:** The instruction at 0x%p referenced memory at 0x%p. The memory could not be %s.





**Windows Error Message:** Invalid access to memory location.

Comment: I am using conda with Python 3.7 but still get the error: 3221225477