# Issue installing Pillow using pipenv

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library, pipenv

I cannont install Pillow using pipenv.  I am new to virtual environments and wanted to set one up for my current project. I have a web app using Flask and Pillow. In order to follow best practice I should be using a virtual environment. I chose pipenv as a YouTube Channel I like suggested using it. https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCCezIgC97PvUuR4_gbFUs5g

```
Windows 10 
Bash
pipenv
python 3.6
```

I've tried the followging:

```
pipenv install Pillow
python3 -m pipenv install Pillow
and many others....
```

I would expect Pillow to be installed.  I know there are other virtual environments I could try. I want to use a good current system. It sounds like pipenv may be the future.

Anyone using pipenv have an idea? Or is it "use virtual environment X"?

Comment: *I would expect Pillow to be installed.* And what did you get instead?

Comment: Are you sure that your virtual environment is activated. Try running `pipenv shell` and then `pipenv install pillow`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: 
Not sure exactly how I solved it but updating everything may have fixed it. I updated conda and all pip files. The next day it worked.

```
conda update --all
```

Pip update all found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/upgrading-all-packages-with-pip)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but it solve when the internet been good 
i use this command 
`pip install pillow`