# Error while installing numpy on anaconda prompt environment

Tags: conda

it show this option
proceed<[y]/n>? y(typed)

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

EnvironmentNotWritableError: The current user does not have write permission to the target environment.

Comment: Run it as administrator.

Comment: hi,after doing this ,when import numpy  i got  " OS ERROR"  in Jupyter nootebook.  OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Comment: This will help you: [OSError Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56724023/oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-when-trying-to-imp)

Comment: What command(s) lead to that error? We need more information than this.