# Issue with Pandas module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I just installed "Pandas" in python using "pip install pandas" but it keeps posting a error about another module called "ctypes".

Error:

[image]

I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please follow the [tour] and read [ask]. Right now, the best we can tell you is that something is wrong with your code in the `data_dump.py` file. We can only tell you anything specific about the code, if you show us the code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56724023/oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-when-trying-to-imp[PLEASE SEE THIS: ANSWER FOR YOURQUESTION][1]

Comment: Thank you it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I don't understand your question correctly, you need to run your application through a virtual env. if you are using conda, `conda activate ./your-venv`, if pip, `your-venv\Scripts\activate`

Comment: I'm just doing simple import statement in my code.