# How to use the selector to target all except the first one

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I want to choose all of the targeting items except the first one. I used ': nth-of-type(n+2)', but the system shows the error: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type

like this:

`data1 = soup1.select('#zoom > div > p:nth-of-type(n + 2)')..`

Comment: I have already tried :not(:nth-of-type(1)) & : nth-of-type(n + 2)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your version of `beautifulsoup`, make sure you are using version at least `4.7.1+`.

In lower versions more advanced CSS selectors weren't supported.

To get your actual version you can do

```
import bs4

print(bs4.__version__)
```

Prints:

```
4.8.0
```

---

Then you can do CSS selector e.g. `p:not(:nth-child(1))`:

```
data = '''<div>
  <p>
    1
  </p>
  <p>
    2
  </p>
  <p>
    3
  </p>
</div>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
print( soup.select('p:not(:nth-child(1))') )
```

Prints:

```
[<p>
    2
  </p>, <p>
    3
  </p>]
```

Comment: Yeah my version is 4.6.0. Could you please tell me the code to update it in terminal?

Comment: @JiaqiNie you could do `python -m pip install -U bs4` from terminal. More info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/how-to-upgrade-all-python-packages-with-pip

Comment: @JiaqiNie Are you sure you are using the correct version of Python and correct version of `bs4`? Are you using Jupyter notebook or other versions of Python? It seems you have mismatch in used versions of python