# How to avoid updating a package from PyPI?

Tags: python, setup.py, pypi, python-packaging

By accident I created a local python package with the same name as an existing PYPI package (pyea).Now I realised that by updating all installed packages my package will be overwritten by a newer version from PYPI-Server. Can I give my local package a flag or so, to prevent from updating using PYPI-Server? Or there are maybe some parameters for the setup.py file to control this issue.

Renaming the package would require a lot of effort.

Comment: If you want others to be able to use your package, renaming is your best option really.

Comment: How are you updating all packages (and why?)

Comment: Many thanks for the response. Even if it was not that what I want to hear. The update will be carried out like explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5839291

Answer (score 1):

It is best practice to avoid using names of packages that already exist. While renaming might be a lot of effort, it's your best option to avoid any future hassle.

It'll be a short term pain for a long term gain.

Comment: As workaround I was considering to change my version number to be above the version hosted on the PYPI server.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess it depends on who this program is for - if it's personal use then it probably will be fine.

Comment: I am still a little bit confused what to do now. I was considering to rename the package from "pyea" to "py_ea". I now recon, that despite the "pyea" package on PyPI a new package py-pea was created a few days ago. So what I am going to do, if someone consider to create a "py_ea" package in the future on PyPI? I am then facing the same problem again. Existing there any naming conventions for local python packages to prevent this issue?

Comment: Maybe you could consider adding the project name to the package? Or your username or something. This, unfortunately, isn't something I have much experience with so I'm not sure on what the best solution it.