# pip requires password after upgrading outdated packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3452888/5920411) to upgrade the outdated Python packages on my Machine running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. I am using `pip 20.0.2`.

Now, every time I try to install or upgrade a package, an annoying window pops up asking for the passowrd. For example:

```sh
pip install --user -U numpy
```

I get the following window:

[image]

When I press **Cancel**, I get the following output:

```
WARNING: Keyring is skipped due to an exception: Failed to unlock the collection!
WARNING: Keyring is skipped due to an exception: Failed to unlock the collection!
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.18.1)
```

Before this issue, I used to install my packages without sudo privileges and without using the `--user` flag.

What is wrong with pip? How can I fix that?.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: This seems less to do with `pip` and more with ubuntu. see https://askubuntu.com/questions/918712/the-login-keyring-did-not-get-unlocked-when-you-logged-into-your-computer for example

Comment: I'm getting this error too, using Fedora. I'm logged in remotely so I can't see the dialog box, if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "**User Accounts**", set "**automatic login**" to "**off**". At startup, you will be asked your user/password only once; I hope it will fix your problem.

Answer (score -2):

After years of getting this and similar issues with `pip` the only solution that has worked every time is to work inside `conda`.