# How to update all installed packages/modules in python using a single "cmd" command in Windows OS?

Tags: python-3.x, package

I want to update all outdated packages of python at once using a ***single*** line command in Windows OS.

Comment: It is already answered here: [How to upgrade all python packages with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/how-to-upgrade-all-python-packages-with-pip)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upgrade all Python packages with pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/how-to-upgrade-all-python-packages-with-pip)