# cannot import name 'force_text' from 'django.utils.encoding'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

Things suddenly started breaking when trying to use `rest_framework_simplejwt`. Now when I run `python manage.py runserver` I get the following:

```
raise InvalidTemplateLibrary(
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'rest_framework.templatetags.rest_framework': cannot import name 'force_text' from 'django.utils.encoding' (/Users/saulfeliz/Dropbox/macBook/Documents/Learning/drf/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py)
```

Searching online, I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70524028/importerror-cannot-import-name-force-text-from-django-utils-encoding-usr) that seemed to work for some. However, when I tried that hack, I get the following exception:

```
raise InvalidTemplateLibrary(
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'rest_framework.templatetags.rest_framework': cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist' from 'django.db.models.fields' (/Users/saulfeliz/Dropbox/macBook/Documents/Learning/drf/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py)
```

This is my **requirements.txt**

```
algoliasearch-django>=2.0,<3.0
django>=4.0.0,<4.1.0
djangorestframework
djangorestframework-simplejwt
pyyaml
requests
django-cors-headers
black
isort
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63300404/makemigration-error-on-django-importerror-cannot-import-name-fielddoesnotexi