# pandas.read_excel raises TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

I'm trying to read an excel file in freshly installed `pandas` using `read_excel` function.

Unfortunately, it raises an error:

```
cities_xlsx = pandas.read_excel(cities_xlsx_path)
```

---

```
~/.virtualenvs/osobnimakleri2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/defusedxml/common.py in iterparse(source, events, parser, forbid_dtd, forbid_entities, forbid_external)
    103                   forbid_entities=True, forbid_external=True):
    104         if parser is None:
--> 105             parser = DefusedXMLParser(target=_TreeBuilder(),
    106                                       forbid_dtd=forbid_dtd,
    107                                       forbid_entities=forbid_entities,

~/.virtualenvs/osobnimakleri2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/defusedxml/ElementTree.py in __init__(self, html, target, encoding, forbid_dtd, forbid_entities, forbid_external)
     66                  forbid_external=True):
     67         # Python 2.x old style class
---> 68         _XMLParser.__init__(self, html, target, encoding)
     69         self.forbid_dtd = forbid_dtd
     70         self.forbid_entities = forbid_entities

TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given
```

Module versions:

```
Python 3.8.5
xlrd==1.2.0
pandas==1.1.4
```

Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: This could be useful https://github.com/tiran/defusedxml/issues/34 as to the cause of the problem

Comment: I researched a lot about the problem and the solution that worked for me was updating all the python modules to the latest version. Below is the snippet that i used for updating the modules.
pip list --outdated --format=freeze | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 pip install -U

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/how-to-upgrade-all-python-packages-with-pip

Comment: "Do you know where is the problem?" Did you try to check the version of defusedxml? If not, why not? (Hint: **according to the stack trace**, which code is running where the error occurs?) See in the stack trace how it has a note about special handling for a "Python 2.x old style class", immediately above the line that supposedly fails? Given that the project is **not** using Python 3.x, does that not immediately stand out as suspicious?

Answer (score 1):

I've downgraded `XLRD` to version `1.1.0` and it's working now.

```
pip install xlrd==1.1.0
```

Comment: This helps resolve the above issue but you might face `module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'` AttributeError with xlrd 1.1.0

Answer (score -1):

I resolved the issue by upgrading both **DefusedXML** and **openpyxl**.

```
df = pd.read_excel(path, engine='openpyxl')
DefusedXML > 0.8
openpyxl > 3.2
```