# This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 87 Current browser version is 90.0.4430.93

Tags: python, selenium

ChromeDriver is giving an error about its version being too low: `This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 87 Current browser version is 90.0.4430.93`.

I've updated pip's packages using this answer [How to upgrade all Python packages with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/how-to-upgrade-all-python-packages-with-pip), I've run `conda update --all` from within Anaconda's terminal, and I've tried to implement ChromeDriverManager into the Python script.

Sample of Python script containing ChromeDriverManager:

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager`
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())`
...
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Gives output:

```
====== WebDriver manager ======
Current google-chrome version is 90.0.4430
Get LATEST driver version for 90.0.4430
Driver [/Users/scottmeup/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/mac64/90.0.4430.24/chromedriver] found in cache
...
This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 87 Current browser version is 90.0.4430.93
```

Output of `echo $PATH`

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/scottmeup/.nvm/versions/node/v15.8.0/bin:/Users/scottmeup/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/scottmeup/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

output of `python --version`

```
Python 3.7.10
```

Output of `pip list`

```
    Package                                Version
-------------------------------------- -------------------
alabaster                              0.7.12
anaconda-client                        1.7.2
anaconda-navigator                     2.0.1
anaconda-project                       0.9.1
anyio                                  2.2.0
applaunchservices                      0.2.1
appnope                                0.1.2
appscript                              1.1.2
argh                                   0.26.2
argon2-cffi                            20.1.0
asn1crypto                             1.4.0
astroid                                2.5
astropy                                4.2.1
async-generator                        1.10
atomicwrites                           1.4.0
attrs                                  20.3.0
autopep8                               1.4.4
Babel                                  2.9.0
backcall                               0.2.0
backports.functools-lru-cache          1.6.4
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size     1.0.0
backports.tempfile                     1.0
backports.weakref                      1.0.post1
beautifulsoup4                         4.9.3
bitarray                               1.9.2
bkcharts                               0.2
bleach                                 3.3.0
bokeh                                  2.3.1
boto                                   2.49.0
Bottleneck                             1.3.2
brotlipy                               0.7.0
castero                                0.8.1
certifi                                2020.12.5
cffi                                   1.14.5
chardet                                4.0.0
chromedriver                           2.24.1
chromedriver-binary                    91.0.4472.19.0
chromedriver-py                        90.0.4430.24
CJKwrap                                2.2
click                                  7.1.2
cloudpickle                            1.6.0
clyent                                 1.2.2
colorama                               0.4.4
conda                                  4.10.1
conda-build                            3.21.4
conda-package-handling                 1.7.3
conda-repo-cli                         1.0.3
conda-token                            0.2.0
conda-verify                           3.4.2
configparser                           5.0.2
contextlib2                            0.6.0.post1
crayons                                0.4.0
cryptography                           3.4.7
cycler                                 0.10.0
Cython                                 0.29.23
cytoolz                                0.11.0
dask                                   2021.4.0
decorator                              4.4.2
defusedxml                             0.7.1
diff-match-patch                       20200713
distributed                            2021.4.0
docutils                               0.17
entrypoints                            0.3
enum-compat                            0.0.3
et-xmlfile                             1.0.1
fastcache                              1.1.0
filelock                               3.0.12
flake8                                 3.7.9
Flask                                  1.1.2
fsspec                                 0.9.0
future                                 0.18.2
gevent                                 21.1.2
glob2                                  0.7
gmpy2                                  2.0.8
greenlet                               1.0.0
grequests                              0.6.0
h5py                                   2.10.0
HeapDict                               1.0.1
html5lib                               1.1
idna                                   2.10
imageio                                2.9.0
imagesize                              1.2.0
importlib-metadata                     3.10.0
iniconfig                              1.1.1
intervaltree                           3.1.0
ipykernel                              5.3.4
ipython                                7.22.0
ipython-genutils                       0.2.0
ipywidgets                             7.6.3
isort                                  5.8.0
itsdangerous                           1.1.0
jdcal                                  1.4.1
jedi                                   0.15.2
Jinja2                                 2.11.3
joblib                                 1.0.1
json5                                  0.9.5
jsonschema                             3.2.0
jupyter                                1.0.0
jupyter-client                         6.1.12
jupyter-console                        6.4.0
jupyter-core                           4.7.1
jupyter-packaging                      0.7.12
jupyter-server                         1.4.1
jupyterlab                             3.0.14
jupyterlab-pygments                    0.1.2
jupyterlab-server                      2.4.0
jupyterlab-widgets                     1.0.0
keyring                                22.3.0
kiwisolver                             1.3.1
lazy-object-proxy                      1.6.0
libarchive-c                           2.9
llvmlite                               0.36.0
locket                                 0.2.1
lxml                                   4.6.3
MarkupSafe                             1.1.1
matplotlib                             3.3.4
mccabe                                 0.6.1
mistune                                0.8.4
mkl-fft                                1.3.0
mkl-random                             1.2.1
mkl-service                            2.3.0
mock                                   4.0.3
more-itertools                         8.7.0
mpmath                                 1.2.1
msgpack                                1.0.2
multipledispatch                       0.6.0
mygpoclient                            1.8
navigator-updater                      0.2.1
nbclassic                              0.2.6
nbclient                               0.5.3
nbconvert                              6.0.7
nbformat                               5.1.3
nest-asyncio                           1.5.1
networkx                               2.5.1
nltk                                   3.6.1
nose                                   1.3.7
notebook                               6.3.0
numba                                  0.53.1
numexpr                                2.7.3
numpy                                  1.20.1
numpydoc                               1.1.0
olefile                                0.46
openpyxl                               3.0.7
packaging                              20.9
pandas                                 1.2.4
pandocfilters                          1.4.3
parso                                  0.5.2
partd                                  1.2.0
path                                   15.1.2
pathlib2                               2.3.5
pathtools                              0.1.2
patsy                                  0.5.1
pep8                                   1.7.1
pexpect                                4.8.0
pickleshare                            0.7.5
Pillow                                 8.2.0
pip                                    21.0.1
pkginfo                                1.7.0
pluggy                                 0.13.1
ply                                    3.11
prometheus-client                      0.10.1
prompt-toolkit                         3.0.17
psutil                                 5.8.0
ptyprocess                             0.7.0
py                                     1.10.0
pycodestyle                            2.5.0
pycosat                                0.6.3
pycparser                              2.20
pycrypto                               2.6.1
pycurl                                 7.43.0.6
pydocstyle                             6.0.0
pyerfa                                 1.7.3
pyflakes                               2.1.1
Pygments                               2.8.1
pylint                                 2.7.4
pyobjc                                 6.2.2
pyobjc-core                            6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-Accounts              6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook           6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit        6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC       6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-ApplicationServices   6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-Automator             6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-AVFoundation          6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-AVKit                 6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-CalendarStore         6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork             6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-CloudKit              6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa                 6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration         6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-CoreAudio             6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-CoreAudioKit          6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-CoreBluetooth         6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-CoreData              6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation          6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-CoreMedia             6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-CoreMediaIO           6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-CoreServices          6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-CoreText              6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-CoreWLAN              6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-CryptoTokenKit        6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices    6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-DiscRecording         6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-DiscRecordingUI       6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-DiskArbitration       6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-DVDPlayback           6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-EventKit              6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling     6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-FinderSync            6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents              6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-GameCenter            6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-GameController        6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-GameKit               6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-ImageCaptureCore      6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-IMServicePlugIn       6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit        6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins      6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage        6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-IOSurface             6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-iTunesLibrary         6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping 6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices        6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-libdispatch           6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-LocalAuthentication   6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-MapKit                6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-MediaAccessibility    6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-MediaLibrary          6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-MediaToolbox          6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-MultipeerConnectivity 6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-NetFS                 6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-NotificationCenter    6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory         6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-OSAKit                6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes       6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-PubSub                6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-QTKit                 6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-Quartz                6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-SceneKit              6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver           6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge       6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit             6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-Security              6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-SecurityFoundation    6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-SecurityInterface     6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement     6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-Social                6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-SpriteKit             6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-StoreKit              6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices          6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration   6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-VideoToolbox          6.2.2
pyobjc-framework-WebKit                6.2.2
pyodbc                                 4.0.0-unsupported
pyOpenSSL                              20.0.1
pyparsing                              2.4.7
PyQt5                                  5.15.4
PyQt5-Qt5                              5.15.2
PyQt5-sip                              12.8.1
pyrsistent                             0.17.3
PySocks                                1.7.1
pytest                                 6.2.3
python-dateutil                        2.8.1
python-jsonrpc-server                  0.3.4
python-language-server                 0.31.10
python-mpv                             0.5.2
python-vlc                             3.0.11115
pytz                                   2021.1
PyWavelets                             1.1.1
PyYAML                                 5.4.1
pyzmq                                  20.0.0
QDarkStyle                             3.0.2
QtAwesome                              1.0.2
qtconsole                              5.0.3
QtPy                                   1.9.0
regex                                  2021.4.4
requests                               2.25.1
rope                                   0.18.0
Rtree                                  0.9.7
ruamel-yaml-conda                      0.15.100
scikit-image                           0.18.1
scikit-learn                           0.24.1
scipy                                  1.6.2
seaborn                                0.11.1
selenium                               3.141.0
Send2Trash                             1.5.0
setuptools                             52.0.0.post20210125
simplegeneric                          0.8.1
singledispatch                         0.0.0
six                                    1.15.0
sniffio                                1.2.0
snowballstemmer                        2.1.0
sortedcollections                      2.1.0
sortedcontainers                       2.3.0
soupsieve                              2.2.1
Sphinx                                 3.0.3
sphinxcontrib-applehelp                1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-devhelp                  1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp                 1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-jsmath                   1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp                   1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml          1.1.4
sphinxcontrib-websupport               1.2.4
spyder                                 4.1.3
spyder-kernels                         1.9.4
SQLAlchemy                             1.4.7
statsmodels                            0.12.2
sympy                                  1.8
tables                                 3.6.1
tblib                                  1.7.0
terminado                              0.9.4
testpath                               0.4.4
threadpoolctl                          2.1.0
tifffile                               2020.10.1
toml                                   0.10.2
toolz                                  0.11.1
tornado                                6.1
tqdm                                   4.59.0
traitlets                              5.0.5
typed-ast                              1.4.2
typing-extensions                      3.7.4.3
ujson                                  1.35
undetected-chromedriver                2.1.2
unicodecsv                             0.14.1
urllib3                                1.26.4
watchdog                               1.0.2
wcwidth                                0.2.5
webdriver-manager                      3.4.1
webencodings                           0.5.1
Werkzeug                               1.0.1
wheel                                  0.36.2
widgetsnbextension                     3.5.1
wrapt                                  1.12.1
wurlitzer                              2.1.0
xlrd                                   2.0.1
XlsxWriter                             1.3.8
xlwings                                0.23.0
xlwt                                   1.3.0
xmltodict                              0.12.0
yapf                                   0.31.0
yeecli                                 0.2.0
yeelight                               0.5.3
zict                                   2.0.0
zipp                                   3.4.1
zope.event                             4.5.0
zope.interface                         5.3.0
```

Output of `pip3 list`

```
Package      Version
------------ -------
mercurial    5.7.1
meson        0.57.2
numpy        1.20.2
packaging    20.9
pip          21.1
pyparsing    2.4.7
PyQt-builder 1.9.1
PyQt5        5.15.4
PyQt5-sip    12.8.1
selenium     3.141.0
setuptools   54.2.0
sip          6.0.3
toml         0.10.2
urllib3      1.26.4
wheel        0.36.2
```

Comment: Download new updated chromedriver from [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=90.0.4430.24/). The error is showing because the webdriver is old and it is not computable with new chrome browser.

Comment: ChromeDriver is not a Python package so running `conda update --all` won't help, it needs to be downloaded separately as @SwaroopHumane mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

You should download chromedriver from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads as same as your chrome version

Answer (score 0):

```
def chrome_driver():
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument("--log-level=3")  # disable Info/Error/Warning in Chrome Driver
        os.environ['WDM_LOG_LEVEL'] = '0'  # Disable the logging of ChromeDriverManager()
        return browser: WebDriver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```

https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager/issues/196