# How can I change pip version

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm using python3.8.6 and I need to upgrade to 3.9.x. 
After upgrade the python, myproject.py cannot find a module that already installed using `pip3 install opencv-python`.

when run `python3 myproject.py` occurs error that ModuleNotFoundError tensorflow, and tensorflow should be 2.5.x so I'm trying to install python 3.9.x.

`pip --version` shows `pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)`
How can I change that (python3.8) to (python3.9)?

sorry for my bad English..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upgrade all Python packages with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/how-to-upgrade-all-python-packages-with-pip)

Comment: If `python3` already points to your python3.9, then simply do `python3 -m pip <list/install>` to run pip commands specifically for that version of python

Answer (score 2):

```
python -m pip install –upgrade pip.
```

If you type `pip list` it will show you every package installed and should say something like `WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.3; however, version 21.2.4 is available.`
You should consider upgrading via this command:

```
c:\users\x\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```