# pip3 command to upgrade all packages, that is careful about dependency conflicts?

Tags: python, pip

So far, I have used (via [How to upgrade all Python packages with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/how-to-upgrade-all-python-packages-with-pip/22260015#22260015))

```
pip3 list --format freeze --outdated | cut -d= -f1 | xargs pip3 install --upgrade-strategy eager --upgrade
```

to upgrade all of my Python pip packages. It has so far worked fine for me - except for once, when I got a sort of a conflict message, unfortunately I didn't keep a copy of it; my guess is, it was something similar to this noted here https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies :

```
Due to conflicting dependencies pip cannot install
package_coffee and package_tea:
- package_coffee depends on package_water<3.0.0,>=2.4.2
- package_tea depends on package_water==2.3.1
```

Anyways, now I just tried to install `voila` for my Jupyter installation, and it ended up like this:

```
(notebook) user@server:/home/web/Jupyter$ pip3 install voila
...
Installing collected packages: jupyter-client, voila
  Attempting uninstall: jupyter-client
    Found existing installation: jupyter-client 7.0.3
    Uninstalling jupyter-client-7.0.3:
      Successfully uninstalled jupyter-client-7.0.3
Successfully installed jupyter-client-6.1.12 voila-0.2.13
```

In other words: I've had `jupyter-client-7.0.3` installed before as latest; but now that I wanted to install `voila`, due to `voila` requirements, that latest version got uninstalled, and an earlier version, `6.1.12`, compatible with `voila`, got installed instead.

So now if I want to check outdated packages, I get, as expected, `jupyter-client` listed:

```
(notebook) user@server:/home/web/Jupyter$ pip3 list --format freeze --outdated
jupyter-client==6.1.12
```

... but then, if I run the full pipe command, `pip3 list --format freeze --outdated | cut -d= -f1 | xargs pip3 install --upgrade-strategy eager --upgrade`, then it will want to upgrade `jupyter-client` to 7.0.3, which will then break `voila` (I guess, I dare not try it).

So, is there an upgrade command, that would take a situation like this, and upon such a state during upgrade, prevent changes and give me a notification? Say, something like:

> WARNING: There is an upgrade to jupyter-client=6.1.12 (newest version 7.0.3) - however, installing that package would cause a conflict with the currently installed `voila=0.2.13` package; not proceeding with this upgrade. To force this upgrade regardless, use [...]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upgrading packages in python is never easy due to overlapping (sub)dependencies. There are some tools out there that try and help you manage. At my current job we use [pip-tools](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools). And in some projects we use [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) but I'm less happy about it's handling.

For pip-tools you define your top-level packages in `requirements.in` file, which then resolves the sub(sub-sub)dependencies and outputs them into a `requirements.txt` file.
The benefit of this is that you only worry about your main packages.
You can still upgrade sub dependencies if so desired.

Long story short; blindly updating **all** your packages will most likely never work out as intended or expected. Either packages ARE upgraded, but stop working, or they do work but don't work with another package that was updated because they needed a lower version of that package.

My advice would be to start with your main packages and build up from there using one of the tools mentioned. There isn't a silver bullet for this. Dependency hell is a very real thing in python.

Comment: Many thanks for this, had no idea about `pip-tools`, will be looking into it immediately! Also great to have the current issues with dependency hell written up; as I'm on and off with `pip`, this will be a great resource to refer to, once I've forgotten my current problems `:)`

Comment: It all resolves about the `setup.py` of packages which determine their sub dependencies. Once those start overlapping with different requirements levels, it really starts to get nasty. Does not mean they won't work, but pip will be very unhappy about it. We had two packages with different version requirements of `six` I think it was, luckily the higher version was backward compatible :D And we managed to get rid off one of them hehe. Good luck! Hope this helps. I know your pain!