# pip install numpy==1.21.5 throws TypeError

Tags: numpy, installation, pip

I uninstalled my old numpy version and want to install the newest version with pip 20.3.4, but got this TypeError:

`set() got an unexpected keyword argument 'expires'`

(same Error for pip install numpy)

Comment: with which IDE?

Comment: I am using VS Code.

Comment: Here are some cool solutions in this regard to try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/how-to-upgrade-all-python-packages-with-pip

Comment: When you report a Python error, it is helpful to include the *complete* traceback (i.e. the complete error message) in the question.  There is useful information in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not to specify the version. Just try:

```
pip3 install numpy
```

It will install the latest stable version.

You can also try to install it with `conda`.

If you use conda, you can install NumPy from the defaults or conda-forge channels:

#### Best practice, use an environment rather than install in the base env

conda create -n my-env
conda activate my-env

#### If you want to install from conda-forge

conda config --env --add channels conda-forge

#### The actual install command

conda install numpy

Comment: Thank you! It helps.