# Why is Python's Pandas' read_excel giving print error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, excel

```
import pandas as pd 

data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\davansh.gupta\Downloads\data.xlsx')
data
```

giving error:-

```
"name": "SyntaxError",

"message": "Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)? (__init__.py, line 1187)",

"stack": "Traceback \u001b[1;36m(most recent call last)\u001b[0m:\n\n\u001b[0m  File \u001b[0;32m~\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python311\\site-packages\\IPython\\core\\interactiveshell.py:3550\u001b[0m in \u001b[0;35mrun_code\u001b[0m\n    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)\u001b[0m\n\n\u001b[0m  Cell \u001b[0;32mIn[2], line 1\u001b[0m\n    data = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/davansh.gupta/Downloads/data.xlsx', sheet_name='with_npi')\u001b[0m\n\n\u001b[0m  File \u001b[0;32mc:\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\io\\excel\\_base.py:504\u001b[0m in \u001b[0;35mread_excel\u001b[0m\n    io = ExcelFile(\u001b[0m\n\n\u001b[0m  File \u001b[0;32mc:\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\io\\excel\\_base.py:1550\u001b[0m in \u001b[0;35m__init__\u001b[0m\n    if import_optional_dependency(\"xlrd\", errors=\"ignore\") is None:\u001b[0m\n\n\u001b[0m  File \u001b[0;32mc:\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\compat\\_optional.py:132\u001b[0m in \u001b[0;35mimport_optional_dependency\u001b[0m\n    module = importlib.import_module(name)\u001b[0m\n\n\u001b[0m  File \u001b[0;32mc:\\Python311\\Lib\\importlib\\__init__.py:126\u001b[0m in \u001b[0;35mimport_module\u001b[0m\n    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\u001b[0m\n\n\u001b[0m  File \u001b[0;32m<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1206\u001b[0m in \u001b[0;35m_gcd_import\u001b[0m\n\n\u001b[0m  File \u001b[0;32m<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1178\u001b[0m in \u001b[0;35m_find_and_load\u001b[0m\n\n\u001b[0m  File \u001b[0;32m<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1149\u001b[0m in \u001b[0;35m_find_and_load_unlocked\u001b[0m\n\n\u001b[0m  File \u001b[0;32m<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:690\u001b[0m in \u001b[0;35m_load_unlocked\u001b[0m\n\n\u001b[0m  File \u001b[0;32m<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:936\u001b[0m in \u001b[0;35mexec_module\u001b[0m\n\n\u001b[0m  File \u001b[0;32m<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1074\u001b[0m in \u001b[0;35mget_code\u001b[0m\n\n\u001b[0m  File \u001b[0;32m<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1004\u001b[0m in \u001b[0;35msource_to_code\u001b[0m\n\n\u001b[1;36m  File \u001b[1;32m<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:241\u001b[1;36m in \u001b[1;35m_call_with_frames_removed\u001b[1;36m\n\n\u001b[1;36m  File \u001b[1;32mc:\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\xlrd\\__init__.py:1187\u001b[1;36m\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;33m    print \"EXTERNSHEET(b7-):\"\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;37m    ^\u001b[0m\n\u001b[1;31mSyntaxError\u001b[0m\u001b[1;31m:\u001b[0m Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?\n"
```

This is the only code in the file and the file is not connected to any other program, why is reading excel giving print error?

I am using pandas.**version** = '2.1.4'

Here's the error how it is looking for me:-

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text 

editorTraceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3550 in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  Cell In[2], line 1
    data = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/davansh.gupta/Downloads/data.xlsx', sheet_name='with_npi')

  File c:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py:504 in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(

  File c:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py:1550 in __init__
    if import_optional_dependency("xlrd", errors="ignore") is None:

  File c:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\_optional.py:132 in import_optional_dependency
    module = importlib.import_module(name)

  File c:\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py:126 in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

  File :1206 in _gcd_import

  File :1178 in _find_and_load

  File :1149 in _find_and_load_unlocked
...
  File c:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py:1187
    print "EXTERNSHEET(b7-):"
    ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
```

Comment: Please post the complete traceback

Comment: and your version of Python and pandas using `pandas.__version__` ?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to use a module version written for Python 2 in Python 3.

Comment: No, its latest only..

Comment: Could you please make the error traceback more readable, with some return to next line? It does say Python 3.1.1, but then there may be a few dependencies?

Comment: There's only python and pandas, so there shouldn't be any other dependencies..

Comment: @DevanshGupta Pandas has its own dependancies. The trace back itself shows that it's utilising xlrd. Always use an environment manager (venv, pipenv, whatever) to make an environment for your project, then you can manage dependancies in there, and run it with its own specifically installed packages.

Comment: That looks like xlrd version 0.7.1. That version is 15 years old, and only supports Python versions up to 2.6. Why are you on xlrd version 0.7.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by the `xlrd` package, which is utilized by `pandas` under the hood. (As you can see [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pyproject.toml#L72C106-L72C106), `xlrd` is listed as an optional dependency.)

To verify this, you can run:

```
import xlrd

print(xlrd.__version__)
```

The latest as of this post is `v2.0.1`, and is free of that outdated python 2.x print statement.

So if you are seeing a much older version on your side, likely you'll just need to update the package with:

```
python -m pip install xlrd --upgrade
```

And check the version again afterwards.

Another thing that's worth consider doing is to update all the packages in your python environment, to avoid potential similar issues with other packages. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2720014/9109822) for reference.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As it was mentioned in comments, it seems like some packages you are using are from python 2.x
I suggest using

```
pd.read_excel('your_file.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

If openpyxl is not recognized, install it with pip

**edit:**
the problem seems to be related to xlrd package. you could try:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade xlrd
```

I hope this fixes your issue.

Comment: Already tried and no the pandas version, as mentioned in the next comment is latest..

Comment: @DevanshGupta This answer did not specify Pandas as the problem. Pandas utilises other packages and one or more of those may be from Python 2.